# Pattern for string that does not contain x, constrained to shortest matches only

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I need a pattern for a string that does not contain a specified string, while at the same time respecting the mandate to match only shortest sequences.

For example strings bracketed by `[]` but not containing `o`:

```
string = "[the][quick][brown][fox][jumps][over][the][lazy][dog]";

StringCases[string, x : Shortest["[" ~~ __ ~~ "]"] /; StringFreeQ[x, "o"]]
```

> ```
> {"[the]", "[quick]", "[jumps]", "[the]", "[lazy]"}
> ```

However this is *a poor solution* because the pattern matcher keeps lengthening the test string rather than moving on to the next possible match, causing a tremendous slow-down on longer strings.  Illustrated:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

StringCases[string, x : Shortest["[" ~~ __ ~~ "]"] /; StringFreeQ[Echo@x, "o"]]
```

> [the]
>
> [quick]
>
> [brown]
>
> [brown][fox]
>
> [brown][fox][jumps]
>
> [brown][fox][jumps][over]
>
> [brown][fox][jumps][over][the]
>
> [brown][fox][jumps][over][the][lazy]
>
> . . .

What I actually want can be accomplished with a second filtering operation:

```
StringCases[string, "[" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ "]"];

Pick[%, StringFreeQ[%, "o"]]
```

> ```
> {"[the]", "[quick]", "[jumps]", "[the]", "[lazy]"}
> ```

I would prefer to do this in a single pass.

A solution in the case of a *single-character string* to prohibit is `Except`:

```
StringCases[string, "[" ~~ Shortest[Except["o"] ..] ~~ "]"]
```

> ```
> {"[the]", "[quick]", "[jumps]", "[the]", "[lazy]"}
> ```

At least in *Mathematica* 10.1 [`Except` does not work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39526/121) with more than one character:

```
StringCases[string, "[" ~~ Shortest[Except["ox"] ..] ~~ "]"]
```

> StringExpression::invld: Element Shortest[Except[ox]..] is not a valid string or pattern element in [~~Shortest[Except[ox]..]~~]. >>

In actuality my delimiters are multicharacter as well so I cannot get around this with something like `Except["]"] ..` either.

Is there another approach that is *fast* and doesn't require a second filtering pass in one form or another?