# How do I use ReplaceAll to replace strings of a specified form?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, string-manipulation

Why is

```
"Xabcde" /. "X" ~~ e__ -> e
```

> "Xabcde"

and not

> "abcde"

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/specifying-string-patterns-in-deletecases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
StringReplace["Xabcde", "X" ~~ e__ -> e].
```

`Replace`, et al are for lists/expressions...

Notice that `AtomQ@"Xabcde"` is `True`, so regular (non-string) replace operations only "see" it as a singular entity:

```
"Xabcde" /. "Xabcde" -> 1

(* 1 *)
```

From the docs for `ReplaceAll`: "... to transform each ***subpart***..." - but there is no "subpart" for atoms, so regular replace operations only operate on the string as a complete entity.

If you want to do such things as part of a larger replacement program, something like this can be done:

```
test = {"Xabcde", {1, 2, 3}};

test /. {a_String :> StringReplace[a, "X" ~~ e__ -> e], {a_, b_, c_} :> {b, c}}

(* {"abcde", {2,3}} *)
```

Comment: So that form of pattern will not work with `/.`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Not for your intended result on strings...

Comment: Is there a pattern I can use with `/.` to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Perhaps you should fill in more details on what you're trying to accomplish in the OP?

Comment: Exactly that: Find a pattern to use with `/.` to achieve string pattern matching and replacement.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Again, that *is* what `StringReplace` is for - perhaps I'm being dense and not understanding your question - but see update, perhaps that's your intent?

Comment: Two intents really. I think you've addressed both. One was to see if there was a form that worked with `/.`. The other was to understand why my pattern wasn't working. I'm also curious how is have figured this out from the docs.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Groovy,+1 on question and thanks for accept. I suppose the tutorials and associated docs. under "pattern matching" is a good start - but yes, "figuring things out" from the documentation can sometimes be a bit treacherous.

Comment: Yeah. My takeaway from the docs is that a pattern is a pattern and should work everywhere it matches. (It's not just the docs of course but also the WL API design philosophy, which is based more on rigid — though not always consistent — rules rather than use cases.)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Xabcde" /. a_ :> StringCases[a, _] /. {"X", b__} :> StringJoin[b]
(*"abcde"*)
```