# Can I use StringExpression or RegularExpression to manipulate Symbolic XML?

Tags: pattern-matching, regular-expressions, xml, string-manipulation

Please, consider an XML document containing these fields:

```
...
<example>An example</example>
<project>A project</project>
<projectName>A project name</projectName>
<projectDate>A project date</projectDate>
...
```

To pick up one, this code suffices:

```
Cases[dataXML, XMLElement["project", __, __], Infinity]
```

But what if I need all fields whose name starts with `"project"` ?

None of these is appropriate:

```
Cases[dataXML, XMLElement["project" ~~ _, __, __], Infinity]
Cases[dataXML, XMLElement["project" ~~ __, __, __], Infinity]
Cases[dataXML, XMLElement["project" ~~ ___, __, __], Infinity]
```

and, similarly for regular expressions, too.

An obvious, although a bit deceptive, escamotage is:

```
data = ToString @ dataXML;
ptr = Shortest @ RegularExpression["XMLElement\\[project[^\\]]*\\]"];
StringCases[data, ptr]
```

nevertheless, I would like to understand the motives of the former failure and if it teaches a broader lesson. Bye !

Comment: [Something on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Condition` with `StringMatchQ`:

```
Cases[dataXML, 
 XMLElement[tag_String /; StringMatchQ[tag, "project*"], __], Infinity]
```

because **`Cases` doesn't support string patterns**.

As to *why* it is designed in such a way, I would [cite](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/specifying-string-patterns-in-deletecases/8948#comment25793_8948) [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin):

> I would say that the reason is dead simple <…>. `Cases` and
>   `DeleteCases` work on parsed expressions, while string functions work
>   on strings. These are just so different that mixing them together
>   would be a very wrong design decision IMO.

A more detailed discussion you can find in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8975/280) answer by [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) and in the comments under the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8948/280) by [R. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/r-m).

Comment: We posted in the same moment: great !! Thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an answer, the main point is left totally ununderstood, but it's an useful workaround.

Suppose that xml data are:

```
<test>
<example>An example</example>
<project>A project</project>
<projectName>A project name</projectName>
<projectDate>A project date</projectDate>
</test>
```

This code:

```
tagsList = Import[fileIn, {"XML", "Tags"}]
requestedTags = 
  Select[tagsList, StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression["project.*"]] &];
Cases[dataXML, XMLElement[#, __, __], Infinity] & /@ requestedTags
```

accomplishes the goal:

```
{{XMLElement["project", {}, {"a project"}]}, {XMLElement[
   "projectDate", {}, {"a project date"}]}, {XMLElement[
   "projectName", {}, {"a project name"}]}}
```