# Position and string patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, searching, string-manipulation

I am trying to get `Position` work with patterns.
I have the following code:

```
dat = {"star", "u", "g", "r", "i", "z", "star2", "u", "g", "r", "i", 
   "z", "star3", "u", "g", "r", "i", "z", "star4", "u", "g", "r", "i",
    "z", "Astro", "u", "g", "r", "i", "z"};
Position[dat, "star" ~~ _]
Position[dat, RegularExpression["star."]]
```

Netheir returns anything. What I want is to return position of "star", "star2" etc. How do I properly use patterns with `Position`?

Comment: @kglr No, this does not return the first one. Also it returns empty fields of dimensions of the original list. I would prefer make it work in the way `Position` works and also understand why this does not actually work

Comment: As to the "why?"... [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html) and [string patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#316252289) are two distinct syntactic forms.  `Position` only supports the former.  The reasons for the distinction are discussed in [(8945)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/142).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Position[dat, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, "star" ~~ ___] &)]
```

or

```
Position[dat, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, "star*"] &)]
```

or

```
Position[dat, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "star*"] &), Heads -> False]
```

or

```
Position[StringMatchQ[dat, "star*"], True] (*thanks: @TomD *)
```

> {{1}, {7}, {13}, {19}}

Alternatively,

```
Pick[Range@Length@dat, StringMatchQ[#, "star*"] & /@ dat]
```

> {1, 7, 13, 19}

Comment: Slight variant: `Position[StringMatchQ[#, "star*"], True] &@dat`

Comment: @TomD, much nicer, thank you. Updated with that alternative.

Answer (score 14):

For large lists, this should be snappy:

```
Pick[Range@Length@dat, StringTake[dat, UpTo@4], "star"]
```

and actually, taking advantage of listability,

```
Pick[Range@Length@dat, StringMatchQ[dat, "star*"]]
```

is a bit faster it seems...