# DeleteCases based on string length

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering

I have the following dataset

```
data = {{"one", "two", "three", "a", "b", "c"}, {"four", "five", "d"}}
```

I want to delete all the strings with length < 2. The desired output is:

```
{{"one", "two", "three"}, {"four", "five"}}
```

I found several solutions on this site like:

```
DeleteCases[#, x_ /; Length[x] < 2] & /@ data
```

But none of them resulted in my desired output. Any suggestion?

Comment: `Cases[#, x_ /; StringLength[x] >= 2] & /@ data`

Comment: Tangentially related: [(8945)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/280).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

many ways to do that..

```
DeleteCases[#, s_String /; StringLength[s] < 2] & /@ data
DeleteCases[data, s_String /; StringLength[s] < 2, {2}]
Select[#, StringLength[#] > 1 &] & /@ data
data /. s_String /; StringLength[s] < 2 :> Sequence @@ {}
```

Comment: OP asked for <2  or if you use select >=2. Please correct your answer

Comment: @Jenny_mathy length must be an integer so `>1` and `>=2` are equivalent.

Comment: yes of course. any of those two. >2 was wrong

Comment: @Jenny_mathy oh i see, someone fixed it already for me..

Comment: `RuleDelayed` has the `SequenceHold` attribute, so your last version could have been just `data /. s_String /; StringLength[s] < 2 -> Sequence[]`. In M10.2+ you could also use `Nothing` instead of `Sequence[]`.

Comment: Also, you could use a level spec of {-1} instead of {2} in your second `DeleteCases` example, in case the input is more deeply nested.

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[Select[data[[i]], StringLength@# >= 2 &], {i, Length@data}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Pick[#, UnitStep[StringLength@# - #2], 1] &[data, 2] (*thanks: @AlexeyPopkov*)
```

> {{"one", "two", "three"}, {"four", "five"}}

Comment: Note that `StringLength` is `Listable`, so your solution can be simplified to `Pick[#, UnitStep[StringLength@# - #2], 1] &[data, 2]`.

Comment: Great point, thank you @Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{"one", "two", "three", "a", "b", "c"}, {"four", "five", "d"}}
data // Map[StringLength@# >= 2 &, #, {-1}] & // Pick[data, #] & (*{2}->{-1}*)
```

Comment: With third argument of `Map` being `{-1}` instead of `{2}` your solution generalizes to arbitrary deeply nested lists of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map[Cases[__?(StringLength[#] >= 2 &)]][data]
Map[Cases[x__/;StringLength[x] >= 2]][data]
```

Comment: The OP asked for removing <2, so you should use >=2.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks. forgot to double check it