# DeleteCases not working as expected

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, language-design

I am trying to reproduce the example of Data Cleaning from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CleanUpDataImportedFromAWebsite.html).
I had to make a slight change in *input 13* to

```
j[x_] := If[StringMatchQ[x, "TOTAL*"], x, DateList[x]];
```

After running *input 14* I get the following data:

[image: data]

There is a *TOTAL* row for every year. The article proposes to delete those rows by running (asterisk is my contribution)

```
tmp4 = DeleteCases[tmp3, {"TOTAL*", __}];
```

but it doesn't work! After searching StackExchange, I found that `DeleteCases` is not compatible with [string patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/specifying-string-patterns-in-deletecases).

So how do we delete those rows? And if `DeleteCases` is truly incompatible, how did the Mathematica article succeed?

PS: I did manage to delete those rows by sorting the data and dropping them, but I'd still like to know how to do it with `DeleteCases`.

Thanks,

Thad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simpler example

```
tmp3 = {{"TOTAL*", 1, 2}, {"TOTAL123", 1, 2}, {a, b, c}};
```

Your code deletes only the first element in which the first entry literally matches `"TOTAL*"`

```
DeleteCases[tmp3, {"TOTAL*", __}]
{{"TOTAL123", 1, 2}, {a, b, c}}
```

To get the desired result you need to specify the first element of list in the pattern to be matched as a `String` which `StringMatch`es the string pattern `"TOTAL*"`. You can do this  using [PatternTest (?)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) or using [Condition (/;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html):

```
DeleteCases[tmp3, {_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "TOTAL*"] &), __}] (* or *)
DeleteCases[tmp3, {s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "TOTAL*"], __}]
```

> {{a, b, c}}