# Matching combinations of StringExpressions and general patterns i

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Is there a clean way to match patterns that combine general patterns and ?`StringExpression`

For example, `Cases` will not match any parts in this construction:

```
{{"my Foo", 1}, {"my Bar", "a"}, {"your Foo", "b"}, {"your Bar", 4}} // Cases[{"my" ~~ __, _Integer}]
```

> {}

Of course `StringCases` can be used on the string expression parts but then

```
{{"my Foo", 1}, {"my Bar", "a"}, {"your Foo", "b"}, {"your Bar", 4}} // 
  Map[First] // StringCases["my" ~~ __]
```

> {{"my Foo"}, {"my Bar"}, {}, {}}

This seems a very basic question, I'd be surprised if it hasn't been asked before but didn't find anything with a cursory search.

Comment: [Specifying string patterns in DeleteCases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/142) poses a similar question.  I think the answers there would apply here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition) and [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ):

```
{
    {"my Foo",1},{"my Bar","a"},{"your Foo","b"},{"your Bar",4}
} //Cases[{s_ /; StringMatchQ[s,"my"~~__], _Integer}]
```

> {{"my Foo", 1}}

Comment: Is there a way to define a smarter version of `Cases` that
applies `StringMatchQ` to  `StringExpression` wherever these appear input expression?