# What is the correct pattern to DeleteCases from a list?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to get better with pattern matching but even after years of using MMA it's still a murky concept. The docs are actually pretty good in this regard but I still struggle. In this situation I have a list of real estate items (that are strings) which I'm trying to clean up. I've tried the below 2 methods and have not been able to delete the "HVAC" elements required from this list.

```
DeleteCases[featureList, StringContainsQ [#,"HVAC"] & ]
```

and

```
DeleteCases[featureList, __~~"HVAC"~~__]
```

Both return the same list back:

```
{ML #,Property Type,SubSpcSqFt,Land Sz SF,Building Type,List Date,Yr Blt,Address,Area,Class,Clear Ceiling Ht (Feet),Lot Frontage (ft),Lot Depth (ft),Zone,Price,Sale Type,Transaction Type,Zoning/Land Use,Amenities-HVAC System,Building Type-Freestanding,HVAC-See Realtor Remarks,HVAC-Baseboard,HVAC-Central A/C,HVAC-Common Water Heater,HVAC-Electric,HVAC-Forced Air,HVAC-Heat Pump,HVAC-Hot Water,HVAC-In-Floor,HVAC-Make-Up Air,HVAC-Mixed,HVAC-None,HVAC-Radiant,HVAC-Rooftop,HVAC-Separate Controls,HVAC-Separate HVAC Units,HVAC-Separate Water Heaters,HVAC-Space Heaters,HVAC-Steam,HVAC-Window A/C}
```

*What is the correct way to filter out any string containing "HVAC"?*

Comment: related: [Specifying string patterns in DeleteCases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/142)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
featureList = {"ML #", "Property Type", "SubSpcSqFt", "Land Sz SF", 
   "Building Type", "List Date", "Yr Blt", "Address", "Area", "Class",
    "Clear Ceiling Ht (Feet)", "Lot Frontage (ft)", "Lot Depth (ft)", 
   "Zone", "Price", "Sale Type", "Transaction Type", 
   "Zoning/Land Use", "Amenities-HVAC System", 
   "Building Type-Freestanding", "HVAC-See Realtor Remarks", 
   "HVAC-Baseboard", "HVAC-Central A/C", "HVAC-Common Water Heater", 
   "HVAC-Electric", "HVAC-Forced Air", "HVAC-Heat Pump", 
   "HVAC-Hot Water", "HVAC-In-Floor", "HVAC-Make-Up Air", 
   "HVAC-Mixed", "HVAC-None", "HVAC-Radiant", "HVAC-Rooftop", 
   "HVAC-Separate Controls", "HVAC-Separate HVAC Units", 
   "HVAC-Separate Water Heaters", "HVAC-Space Heaters", "HVAC-Steam", 
   "HVAC-Window A/C"};
```

The following are all equivalent

```
DeleteCases[featureList, _?(StringContainsQ[#, "HVAC"] &)]

DeleteCases[featureList, _?(StringContainsQ["HVAC"])]

DeleteCases[featureList, _?(StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "HVAC" ~~ ___] &)]

DeleteCases[featureList, _?(StringMatchQ[___ ~~ "HVAC" ~~ ___])]

Select[featureList, StringFreeQ["HVAC"]]
```

Comment: It would be fine to add he alternative solution : `Select[featureList, ! StringContainsQ[#, "HVAC"] &]`

Comment: Excellent answer. I found this doc helpful in understanding the behaviour of this answer: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html

Answer (score 4):

In addition:

```
DeleteCases[featureList, str_/;StringContainsQ[str, "HVAC"]]
```

But perhaps combined with a regular expression is more powerful?

For example (delete cases where `str` begins with 'HVAC' only):

```
 DeleteCases[featureList, str_/;StringContainsQ[str, 
  RegularExpression["^HVAC"]]]
```

> {ML #, Property Type, SubSpcSqFt, Land Sz SF, Building Type, List Date, Yr Blt, Address, Area, Class, Clear Ceiling Ht (Feet), Lot Frontage (ft), Lot Depth (ft), Zone, Price, Sale Type, Transaction Type, Zoning/Land Use, Amenities-HVAC System, Building Type-Freestanding}

And, of course, there is also `Pick`

```
Pick[featureList,StringContainsQ[featureList,"HVAC"],False]
```

Comment: Ah. Good answer too. I was more confused about `patterns` but there are a lot of `regex` gurus out there.