# How to define a mixed pattern consisting of string and regular patterns for function definition (using SetDelayed)?

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, argument-patterns

I'm kinda stuck here, and I could *really* use some help:

I want to define a function, let's call it `quarterValue`, that accepts a `Rule` as an input and returns an appropriate expression as output.

A template expression (a *type* of sorts?) of what the input is expected to be, is given below:

```
StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter] -> _?NumericQ
```

and as far as the output is concerned, I was going to give three different `quarterValue` definitions in order to account for the different possible input configurations (presented here from the most specific to the least specific), namely

```
ClearAll[quarterValue]
quarterValue::err = "Error: `1`->`2`: `3`";

(* catch missing values *)
quarterValue[(q:StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]) -> ""] := q -> Missing[]

(* regular input *)
quarterValue[(q:StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]) -> (nmc_?NumericQ)] := q -> nmc

(* account for irregular input etc *)
(* emit a Message and return the input unevaluated *)
quarterValue[e:((q:StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]) -> x_)] := (
  Message[quarterValue::err, q, x, e];
  e
 )
```

I thought I was smart enough but the Kernel had other plans.

I was anticipating that

```
quarterValue[StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter] -> (whatever_)]
```

would match against input values, because `StringMatchQ["Qi", StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]]`, where `i` is any value from `{1,2,3,4}`, matches every possible `lhs` of the input `Rule` and either `""` or `_?NumericQ` or `_` match the *rhs* of the input `Rule`.

It seems that, this is not the case.

How can I mix string and regular patterns in order to make the `SetDelayed` definition of `quarterValue` evaluate correctly?

Comment: Similar: [8945](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/142)

Comment: Although `StringMatchQ["Q1", StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]]` matches,  `StringMatchQ[StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter], 
 StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]]` does not match because `StringMatchQ[StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]` is not a string, but a string expression containing a symbolic string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to make it work, but I still don't get *why* my original code didn't work as expected.

The solution I figured out is to check for the quarter string pattern using a pattern test:

```
ClearAll[quarterValue]

quarterValue::err = "Error: `1`->`2`: `3`";

(*catch missing values*)
quarterValue[q_ -> ""] /; StringMatchQ[q, StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]] :=  q -> Missing[]

(*regular input*)
quarterValue[q_ -> (nmc_?NumericQ)] /; StringMatchQ[q, StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]] := q -> nmc

(*account for irregular input etc*)
(*emit a Message and return the input unevaluated*)
quarterValue[e : (q_ -> x_)] /; StringMatchQ[q, StringExpression["Q", DigitCharacter]] := (
  Message[quarterValue::err, q, x, e];
  e
 )
```

This way all the following expressions evaluate as expected:

```
quarterValue["Q1" -> ""]
(* "Q1" -> Missing[] *)

quarterValue["Q3" -> 12.120]
(* "Q3" -> 12.12 *)

quarterValue["Q2" -> "x"]
(* quarterValue: Error. x should be NumericQ or \"\" *)
(* "Q2" -> "x" *)
```

Comment: Simply put: you can only use string patterns inside special functions like `StringMatchQ`. I would also recommend using `quarterValue[q_String -> ""] /; StringMatchQ[q,...]` instead because otherwise StringMatchQ can start spilling messages when `q` is not a string.