# ReplaceAll on a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Does replacing a list of strings have to be this convoluted (with a warning too)? Why can't `ReplaceAll` natively use string matching patterns?

```
s = {"dir abc", "wfori", "dir ej99", "lkdwk", "pokp"};

s /. {x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "dir " ~~ ___] -> "X"}
s /. {"dir " ~~ ___ -> "X"}

(* {"X", "wfori", "X", "lkdwk", "pokp"} *)
(* {"dir abc", "wfori", "dir ej99", "lkdwk", "pokp"} *)
```

I know there's `StringReplace` but then, it hasn't the "built-in" ability to remove an element like `ReplaceAll` does

```
s /. {x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "dir " ~~ ___] -> Nothing}
StringReplace[{"dir abc", "wfori", "dir ej99", "lkdwk", "pokp"}, "dir " ~~ ___ -> Nothing]

(* {"wfori", "lkdwk", "pokp"} *)
(* {StringExpression[Nothing], "wfori", StringExpression[Nothing], "lkdwk", "pokp"} *)
```

Comment: `Select[StringFreeQ["dir"]][s]`

Comment: @Syed thanks, there are many workarounds, but is not about a particular solution, I'd like to understand better if `ReplaceAll` can't work at all... For anything other but strings I could use `ReplaceAll` both for actual replacing or "delete" something from a list and this capability is much powerful than relying on two different methods to replace/delete strings in a list... Does it have to be this way?

Comment: `StringReplace` only works on strings. If you make the pattern more restrictive by replacing `x_` with `x_String` then you get no warning.

Comment: There was a similar question about why there is a distinction between general patterns and string patterns in [Specifying string patterns in DeleteCases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/142).

Comment: @WReach thanks it's exactly the answer I was looking for