# Mysterious behaviour of Pick

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

As everyone knows, `Pick` can do amazing things, The most fascinating phenomenon is that it can pick though all sorts of lists:

The basic & pattern matching:

```
Pick[{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 1}, 1]
(*{4,6}*)

Pick[{4,5,6},{1,2,3},_?(#<3&)]
(*{4,5}*)
```

The most facinating thing is that it can match through ragged list and you can even make the thing you want to pick almost arbitraryly!

```
Pick[{2, {3, 4}}, {3, {4, 5}}, 5]
(*{{4}}*)

Pick[{2, {3, 4}}, {3, {4, 5}}, {4, 5}]
(*{{3,4}}*)
```

But the mysterious behaviour occurs here:

Sometimes we need to Pick from Complex ragged lists with list as its element, and sometime we need to Pick according to similar lists. It's quite hard to handle for `Pick`, but most times it do perfectly. In the following case, it successfully pick through multiple levels and all sorts of pattern:

```
Pick[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {1} | 2 | {4, 5}]
(*{{1, 2}, {2}, {6}}*)
```

As you can see, it can match through {1} | 2 | {4, 5}. It's quite natural to think that if we only want to match one of them, for example, {4,5}, it would be quite easy and the result should be {{},{},{6}}, but actually it simply won't do the job and return error message telling me that the shape is not the same:

```
Pick[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {4, 5}]
```

Is this a bug and how to solve this problem? Or maybe it's too hard for computer to find a proper match shape with the mere information I give it?

Comment: Based on the docs, it doesn't seem like the `{1} | 2 | {4, 5}` example should work at all

Comment: @JasonB why? it should work i suppose, at this level it is correspondent

Comment: The docks say "The "selector" list has to have the same length and structure as the data" - although it isn't clear what "structure" means *exactly*.  It would be useful if you could specify the level at which to apply this *same structure* test, but it doesn't seem that you can

Comment: I guess your case can be explained by the "Using nonatomic expressions in the selector argument can lead to unexpected results" example in "possible issues"

Comment: you can say that~@happy fish

Comment: Related: [(4946)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4946/121), [(59272)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59272/121)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is not a bug.  It is a consequence of the manner in which `Pick` scans its arguments.

**The `Pick` Process**

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) for `Pick` calls its arguments *list*, *sel* and *patt*.  `Pick` scans the *list* and *sel* expressions lock-step in a top-down, left-to-right fashion.  It proceeds roughly as follows:

1. The entire *sel* expression is checked to see if it matches *patt*.  If it does, then *list* is returned as the result.
2. If either *list* or *sel* are atomic, the result is `Sequence[]` and the scan stops.
3. If this point is reached, both *list* and *sel* have subparts that can be scanned.  However, if the lengths of the expressions are not the same then the process is aborted with the `Pick::incomp` message.  Note that the heads do not have to match -- just the number of subparts.
4. If this point is reached, both *list* and *sel* have the same number of subparts.  The whole process is repeated recursively for corresponding pairs of elements in the two expressions.  Successfully picked subparts of *list* are gathered into a resultant expression whose head is the same as the head of *list*.  Note that recursive occurrences of `Sequence[]` from step 2 will cause mismatches to be dropped out of the final result.

**The Cases At Hand**

Let us first consider this expression, which "works":

```
Pick[
  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5     , 6     }}
, {{1   }, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}
, {1} | 2 | {4, 5}
]

(* {{1, 2}, {2}, {6}} *)
```

(Step 1) The entire *sel* expression (`{{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}`) is checked to see if it matches the pattern.  It does not.

(Step 2) Neither *list* nor *sel* is atomic, so scanning descends to the next level.

(Step 3) Both *list* and *sel* have three elements, so the shapes are compatible.  A resultant object will be created using the head of *list*, namely `List`.

(Step 4) The whole process is repeated for corresponding elements from *list* and *sel*:

(Element 1 - Step 1) The first element of *sel* (`{1}`) is checked to see if it matches the pattern.  It does, so the first element of *list* (`{1, 2}`) is added to the resultant `List` from step 4 above.

(Element 2 - Step 1) The second element of *sel* `{2, 3}` is checked to see if it matches the pattern.  It does not.

(Element 2 - Step 2) Neither the second element of *sel* (`{2, 3}`) nor its *list* partner (`{2, 3}`) are atomic so the process continues.

(Element 2 - Step 3) The elements `{2, 3}` and `{2, 3}` have the same length so the process continues.

(Element 2 - Step 4) A resultant expression will be constructed with the head `List` and scanning recurses down to the next level.

(Element 2, 1 - Step 1) The *sel* element `2` matches the pattern and the corresponding *list* element `2` is added to the result.

(Element 2, 2 - Step 1) The element `3` does not match the pattern.

(Element 2, 2 - Step 2) The element `3` is atomic, so `Sequence[]` (i.e. nothing) is contributed to the result.  This is the last element in this sublist, so this recursive subprocess is complete.

(Element 3 - Step 1) The third element of *sel* (`{{3, 4}, {4, 5}}`) does not match the pattern.

(Element 3 - Step 2) Neither the third element of *sel* nor its *list* partner `{5, 6}` are atomic so the process continues.

(Element 3 - Step 3) The two lists have compatible lengths so the process continues.

(Element 3 - Step 4) A resultant expression will be constructed with the head `List` and scanning recurses down to the next level.

(Element 3, 1 - Step 1) `{3, 4}` does not match the pattern so `Sequence[]` (i.e. nothing) is contributed to the result.

(Element 3, 2 - Step 1) `{4, 5}` matches the pattern so the corresponding expression `6` is contributed to the result.

At this point, *list* and *sel* have been scanned entirely.  The final result is returned.

Now let us consider the expression that "does not work":

```
Pick[
  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5     , 6     }}
, {{1   }, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}
, {4, 5}
]

(* Pick::incomp: Expressions have incompatible shapes. *)
```

The first four steps proceed exactly as in the preceding example.  Scanning descends recursively into the subparts of *list* and *sel*.  However, trouble arises when processing the first pair of subparts.  `{1}` does not match the pattern, so the process wants to descend recursively again.  But the *sel* expression `{1}` does not have the same number of parts as the *list* expression `{1, 2}`.  Thus, the process aborts with the "incompatible shapes".

**Is this all detailed in the documentation?**

Umm, maybe??  I can't find it.

**Okay then, is any of this observable?**

Yes!  The following helper function is useful to get a peek into the internals of any pattern-matching process:

```
tracePattern[patt_] :=
    _?(((Print[#, " ", #2]; #2)&)[#, MatchQ[#, patt]]&)
```

It looks ugly, but its operation is simple: it returns a pattern that matches the same things as its argument, but prints out each candidate expression with its matching status.  For example:

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, tracePattern[2]]

(* 1 False
   2 True
   3 False

   {2}
 *)
```

*Note: this is a simplistic implementation that is good enough for the present discussion.  A more robust implementation would have to account for the possibility of evaluation leaks and other sordid eventualities.*

Here `tracePattern` is being used to snoop on the `Pick` expression that "works":

```
Pick[
  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5     , 6     }}
, {{1   }, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}
, tracePattern[{1} | 2 | {4, 5}]
]

(* {{1},{2,3},{{3,4},{4,5}}} False
   {1} True
   {2,3} False
   2 True
   3 False
   {{3,4},{4,5}} False
   {3,4} False
   {4,5} True

   {{1,2},{2},{6}}
 *)
```

And here is the expression that "does not work":

```
Pick[
  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5     , 6     }}
, {{1   }, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}
, tracePattern[{4, 5}]
]

(* {{1},{2,3},{{3,4},{4,5}}} False
   {1} False

   Pick::incomp: Expressions have incompatible shapes.
*)
```

A close inspection of these results, along with similar traces for the other `Pick` expressions in the question, will reveal that the processing follows the steps outlined above.

Comment: +1 - beat me to the `Print` sorcery. Very nice answer!

Comment: Maybe you can write a self-answered question that features your "more robust implementation"? In any event, nice stuff!

Comment: WHAT THE HECK!!!!! That's AWESOME!!!!!!I never expect one answer for my question as good as this one! thanks!!!!!

Comment: That is so detailed and instructive! Thank you very very very much!!!!!!

Comment: @WReach will the code in my answer illustrate your point?

Comment: Yes, the code captures the essential elements of the `Pick` process (with an intentionally modified version of step 3).  It probably does not matter for your application, but I'll mention that the built-in `Pick` implementation also handles heads other than `List` and takes care to avoid evaluating held expressions.

Answer (score 8):

Well, as @WReach has already explained the process of Thread clearly, I think I'll simply give a new function to solve this problem and make both examples work.

After knowing the behaviour of Pick, a simple change can solve this problem------Whenever the two parts are not of the same shape, simply pass it and go to the next.

The code is shown below:

```
MyPick[l1_, l2_, pat_] := 
  If[MatchQ[l2, pat], l1, 
   If[Length@l1 == Length@l2 != 0, 
    MapThread[MyPick[##, pat] &, {l1, l2}], Nothing]];

MyPick[l1_, l2_] := Pick[l1, l2]
```

The functionality and usage is exactly the same as `Pick`, So simply and My before `Pick` will give you a desired result:

```
MyPick[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {4, 
  5}]
MyPick[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 
   3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {1} | 2 | {4, 5}]

(* {{}, {6}} *)
(* {{1, 2}, {2}, {6}} *)
```

Great~

I hope this can help someone~