# Is pattern matching just systematic guessing and checking?

Tags: pattern-matching

## How does the pattern matcher work?

how does it match this example?

```
f[3, h[4]] /. f[x_, z_[y_]] :> {x, y, z}
```

My guess is that the pattern matcher collects all the names in the expression `f[3, h[4] ]` in a list `{f, 3, h, 4}` and plugs them in (3 at a time) into  the placeholders (the pattern variables) in the pattern `f[x_, z_[y_]]`?

It searches through all possibilities until it finds a match?

> - {f, 4, 4}   =>  f[f, 4[4] ] => False
> - {3, f, f}  =>  f[3, f[f] ] => False
> - {3, f, 3} => f[3, f[3]] => False
> - {3, f, h} => f[3, f[h]] => False
> - {3, f, 4} => f[3, f[4]] => False
> - {3, 3, f} => f[3, 3[f]] => False
> - {3, 4, h} => f[3, 4[h]] => False
>
>   ### - {3, h, 4} => f[3, h[4]] => True,
> - {3, 3, 4},
> - {3, h, f},
> - {3, 4, f}

I am only guessing I would love to know how it really works?

Comment: No.  It compares part by part.  Does the head match?  You have `f` in both the target expression and the pattern, so yes.  Good, next: does the first argument match?  Yes, `3` matches `_`.  Good, next:  does the second argument match?  That's `h[4]` and we have to test is against a compound pattern.  So you start again with the head ...

Comment: You can read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching and also search for how a regular expression engine might be implemented.

Comment: Playing with `ReplaceList` may give you additional insight, as it returns a list of all matches in the order in which they are generated.

Comment: The answer for [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119223/mysterious-behaviour-of-pick) might give you some idea about how to figure out how the pattern matching process works.