# Delete sublist when sub-sublists contain same element

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sets

Given

```
lis={{{a},{b,c,d}},{{a,b},{b,c}},{{b,c},{a,b,c}},{{b},{d}},{{a,b},{c,d}}}
```

I want to delete sublists which have one or more elements in common. So that I would get

```
{{{a},{b,c,d}},{{b},{d}},{{a,b},{c,d}}}
```

Is there a way without flattening Level 3 first?

Comment: user57467, could you clarify what would be the desired output for input list `lis3 = {{{a, a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}};`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)+ [`ContainsNone`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsNone.html)

```
Select[Apply[ContainsNone]]@lis
```

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

#### `Pick` + `ContainsNone`:

```
Pick[#, ContainsNone @@@ #] & @ lis
```

> > {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

#### [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) + `ContainsNone`

```
Cases[{a_, b_} /; ContainsNone[a, b]]@lis
```

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

#### [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) + [`ContainsAny`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAny.html)

```
DeleteCases[{a_, b_} /; ContainsAny[a, b]]@lis
```

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

#### `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[{{___, a_, ___}, {___, a_, ___}}] @ lis
```

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

**Note:** If either element of the sublist pairs contains duplicates, as in

```
lis2 = {{{a, a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, 
  {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};
```

then

```
Select[Apply[ContainsNone]] @ lis2
Pick[#, ContainsNone @@@ #] & @ lis2
Cases[{a_, b_} /; ContainsNone[a, b]] @ lis2
DeleteCases[{a_, b_} /; ContainsAny[a, b]] @ lis2
DeleteCases[{{___, a_, ___}, {___, a_, ___}}] @ lis2
```

all give

> {{{a, a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

while the methods proposed by @Nasser and @ThatGravityGuy

```
Cases[lis2, {x_, y_} /; Length@Union[x, y] == (Length[x] + Length[y]) :> {x, y}]
Select[lis2, DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten]
```

both give

> {{{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

Comment: You just blew my head off! Great!

Answer (score 10):

I am sure there are many ways to do this. One possible way is to take the union of both sublists, and check if its length is same as sum of length of both sublists. Since when making union, duplicates are automatically removed.

```
lis = {{{a}, {b,c,d}}, {{a,b}, {b,c}}, {{b,c},{a,b,c}}, {{b},{d}}, {{a,b}, {c,d}}};

Cases[lis, {x_, y_} /; Length@Union[x, y] == (Length[x] + Length[y]) :> {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good explanation for your code!

Answer (score 10):

Another method with [`DuplicateFreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html), where `@*` is shorthand/infix notation for [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

```
Select[lis, DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten]
```

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

Another way of really doing the exact same thing is with [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html).

```
Pick[lis, DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten /@ lis]
```

Basically, either method picks out the elements of `lis` such that `DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten[elem] == True`.

Comment: Could you explain the code, please? What is "@*"?

Answer (score 6):

**(1) Pick, IntersectingQ**

```
lis//Pick[#,MapApply[IntersectingQ,#],False]&

(* {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}} *)
```

**(2) Pick, Intersection**

[Syed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81355/syed) has pointed out (in a comment) that the following does not work:

```
Pick[lis,Intersection@@@lis,{}]

(* Pick::incomp: Expressions {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, 
  {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}} and {{}, {b}, {b, c}, 
  {}, {}} have incompatible shapes.*)
```

A great explanation of how `Pick` works has been [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119235/106) by [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach), and `tracePattern` defined in that post illustrates the problem very nicely:

```
Pick[lis,Intersection@@@lis,tracePattern[{}]]

(*
  {{}, {b}, {b, c}, {}, {}} False
  {} True
  {b} False
  Pick::incomp: Expressions {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}},
  {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}} and {{}, {b},
  {b, c}, {}, {}} have incompatible shapes.
 *)
```

If at any stage, as `Pick` recursively scans, "the lengths of the expressions are not the same then the process is aborted with the `Pick::incomp message`".

```
Intersection@@@lis

(* {{}, {b}, {b, c}, {}, {}} *)
```

As `{b}` from the selector list does not match a pattern, the situation is reached where `{b}` (from *sel*) and  `{a,b}` (from `lis`) do not have the same length, and the process aborts.

The following fails for the same reason:

```
 Pick[lis,(MapApply[Intersection]@lis),tracePattern[_?(#==={}&)]]

(* 

  {{}, {b}, {b, c}, {}, {}} False
  {} True
  {b} False
  Pick::incomp: Expressions {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, 
  {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}} and {{}, {b}, 
  {b, c}, {}, {}} have incompatible shapes.
*)
```

If `{b}` is included in the pattern given to `Pick`, then `{{a,b}, {b,c}}` from *lis* with be included in the list returned by `Pick` (this is unwanted behaviour, of course), but the "incompatible shapes" problem is circumvented (in this instance) and, as this problem does not arise in any subsequent (recursive) steps, `Pick` returns a result without an error message:

```
Pick[lis,Intersection@@@lis,tracePattern[{}| {b}]] 

(* 

  {{}, {b}, {b, c}, {}, {}} False
  {} True
  {b} True
  {b, c} False
  b False
  c False
  {} True
  {} True
  {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, {}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, 
   {c, d}}}

  *)
```

**One possible work-around**

```
lis[[Pick[Range@Length@lis,MapApply[Intersection]@lis,{}]]]

(* {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}} *)
```

Just for fun:

```
lis[[Pick[Range@Length@lis,MapApply[Intersection]@lis,
  tracePattern[{}]]]] 

(* 

  {{}, {b}, {b, c}, {}, {}} False
  {} True
  {b} False
  {b, c} False
  {} True
  {} True
  {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}
*)
```

Comment: Could you please say why `Pick[lis,Intersection@@@lis,{}]` does not work? (comment reposted after answer update. Apologies, as I accidentally deleted it). Thanks for the explanation and answer update.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use `DeleteElements` with `ContainsAny` or `IntersectingQ` as follows:

```
lis = {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b, 
     c}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};

res = {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};
```

Then:

```
DeleteElements[lis, {a_, b_} /; ContainsAny[a, b] :> {a, b}] === res
(*True*)
DeleteElements[lis, {a_List, b_List} /; IntersectingQ[a, b] :> {a, b}] === res
(*True*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll` and something from one of @kglr's ways to do this:

```
lis /. {{___, a_, ___}, {___, a_, ___}} :> {a, a} /. {a_, b_} /; a == b :> Nothing

(*{{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b, c}}, 
  {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};
```

Using function deconstruction

```
f[x_] /; Union[Last /@ Tally @ Flatten @ x] == {1} := x

f[_] := Nothing

f /@ list
```

{{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}

Comment: (+1) Nice solution using Tally, @eldo!

Answer (score 0):

**Using `DisjointQ`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lis = {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}, {{b, c}, {a, b, 
     c}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}};

Pick[lis, Map[Apply[DisjointQ]][lis]]
```

or

```
Select[Apply[DisjointQ]][lis]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}