# Pattern test for variables during function definition

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I am having a problem with pattern testing on variables during function definition

```
nfun[M : Repeated[_?(test1&&test2||test3..)&, {10}]]:= N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))
```

I want to have a few tests on the vectors `M` that I want to feed `nfun`. One example that does not work if I want to test if `M` has `Integer` entries using `Repeated` is the following.

```
nfun[M : Repeated[_?IntegerQ, {10}]]:= N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))
```

Here goes another filed trial with the same aim.

```
nfun[M_?((VectorQ[#, IntegerQ]) && (Length[#] == 10)) &]:= N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> nfun[M : Repeated[_IntegerQ, {10}]]:= N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))
> ```

This does not work because `_IntegerQ` is testing an expression for the explicit head `IntegerQ` rather than `Integer`.  Use `_Integer` or generically `_?test`.

For applying a series of tests I recommend:

```
f[M : Repeated[_Integer, {10}]] /; test1[M] && test2[M] || test[M] := {{M}}
```

---

Okay, I see that this is not identical to what you were constructing because of [the difference between `PatternTest` and `Condition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121).  If your aim is to test every element separately it is usually cleanest to establish a single test function and use `_?test`.  For example:

```
test = # < 8 && EvenQ[#] || PrimeQ[#] &;

f[M : Repeated[_?test, {10}]] := {{M}}
```

Comment: However `nfun[M : Repeated[_Integer, {10}]] :=N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))` does not work either if you try `nfun[Range[10]]` and same for the `f` you defined with the `test`. Try `f[M : Repeated[_?test, {4}]] := {{M}};
test[#] & /@ {2, 4, 6, 13}` which gives all true. But `f[{2, 4, 6, 13}]` does not evaluate!

Comment: +1 for a separate function - I agree that it is the cleanest way.

Comment: @PlatoManiac You're mixing your input types.  Try : `nfun @@ Range[10]` or change you definition to account for `List`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I thought `Repeated` will take care of a list with length 10. I saw your answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255210/finding-equal-or-similar-sequences-in-a-list) before I posed my question. How can I use something like `ListQ` in this context of `Repeated` so that `nfun[Range[10]]` works. I am so dumb when it comes to use this fancy patterns :(

Comment: @PlatoManiac don't say you're dumb, this stuff gets complicated!  In this case you need to think of `Repeated` as being a bare "sequence" of elements like `1, 2, 3` without a head, therefore you need `{ Repeated[ stuff ] }` if you want to match a `List` with repeated elements inside it.  This is similar to: `f[ x__ ] :=` versus `f[ {x__} ] :=`

Answer (score 3):

I'd have done `nfun[M : {__Integer}] /; Length[M] == 10 := N@(Norm@(Sin[#] & /@ M))` myself, at least for your specific example.