# Efficient way to test if all the elements in a list are Integers?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Consider a list such as

```
s = {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3}
```

With `IntegerQ[number]` , you know if `number` is an `Integer`, the result is `True`, and if not, the result is `False`.

But how could I do this without visiting each element as in `Do[ ..., {i, 1, Length[...]}]`?

Comment: @kuba, Yes I have viewed the documentation, but I can´t reach the solution. I know that was simple for people who know it. Not for me.

Comment: I looked for a duplicate, but the closest I found was question [8650](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/); in particular, [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652) by Mr.Wizard uses `VectorQ` in the way my answer does.

Comment: I don't know how **easily** the best answer is found, but `ArrayQ` is used to test for a vector of integers here in documentation for [IntegerQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerQ.html#115975965), and one can find `VectorQ` here in the documentation for [ArrayQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayQ.html#248136993).

Comment: Somewhat related:
[916](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/916),
[7120](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7120/), [16694](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16694)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
s = {1,2,3,3,5,6,3};
```

I would write:

```
And @@ (IntegerQ /@ s)
```

**EDIT**

With **V10** we can use:

```
AllTrue[s, IntegerQ]
```

> True

```
NoneTrue[s // N, IntegerQ]
```

> True

Comment: If you want to transcend an array (list of lists) and test each element in the array individually, specify a depth, e.g. for a 2D array try `AllTrue[{{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, a}}, NumericQ, 2]`.

Answer (score 9):

[`VectorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorQ.html) is the best way I know.  Here are three types of input, packed array of `Integer`, an (non-packed) array of `Integer`, and an array of not all `Integer`.

```
packed   = RandomInteger[10, 10^7];
unpacked = Flatten@ConstantArray[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 10^6];
nonint   = ReplacePart[packed, 10^6 -> 1.5];

Developer`PackedArrayQ@unpacked
(* False *)
```

Testing `VectorQ[list, IntegerQ]`:

```
VectorQ[packed, IntegerQ]
VectorQ[unpacked, IntegerQ]
VectorQ[nonint, IntegerQ]
(*
  True
  True
  False
*)
```

Comparing the timings with two other methods (the timing function `timeAvg` is given below):

```
VectorQ[packed, IntegerQ] // timeAvg
VectorQ[unpacked, IntegerQ] // timeAvg
VectorQ[nonint, IntegerQ] // timeAvg
(*
  2.64695*10^-7
  0.0319406
  0.00318189
*)

MatchQ[packed, {___Integer}] // timeAvg
MatchQ[unpacked, {___Integer}] // timeAvg
MatchQ[nonint, {___Integer}] // timeAvg
(*
  9.5835*10^-7
  0.157701
  0.065558
*)

And @@ (IntegerQ /@ packed) // timeAvg
And @@ (IntegerQ /@ unpacked) // timeAvg
And @@ (IntegerQ /@ nonint) // timeAvg
(*
  2.782322
  2.858287
  2.540433
*)
```

You may note that on packed arrays `VectorQ` and `MatchQ` take virtually no time.  In fact, it's the same amount of time no matter what the size.  This is because a packed array is a special efficient internal representation of an array.  In particular it has to be an array of all the same type of number (only `Integer`, `Real`, and `Complex` are allowed).  So checking the type is easy.  See [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)

---

The site-standard `timeAvg` function:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ 
    AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}];
```

Comment: My function seems to unpack, whereas yours circumvents this nasty habit. Thanks, very instructive.

Comment: @eldo Thanks. I think the OP's use-case is unlikely to have a packed list, since it seems possible that not all entries are integers. (Indeed, it must be rare that one would need to do such a test on a packed array.) It appears that mapping `IntegerQ` over the list is the rate-limiting step.

Comment: [I too](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652/121) like `VectorQ` to prevent unpacking. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map`, abbreviated `/@`. For example:

```
  lis = {4, 5/2, 3., 6/3, Pi};
  IntegerQ /@ lis               (* or Map[IntegerQ, lis] *)
```

(* {True, False, False, True, False} *)