# Pick with nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs of values.  Some of those pairs are invalid based on another list.  I would like to select only the valid pairs.

```
list1 = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"};
list2 = {{"abc", 1}, {"def", 2}, {"ghi", 3}, {"jkl", 4}, {"mno", 5}};
sel = {{2}, {}, {4}, {1}, {7}};
Pick[list1, sel, {_}]
Pick[list2, sel, {_}]
```

list1 is a sample of what I would like.  list2 is similar to my actual case.  sel is the result of `Position` where I'm checking a corresponding list against valid cases.  When the result of `Position` is an empty list, I do not want the values in list1 or list2.

The output from the above code is:

[image]

I see from the documentation that what I'm doing with list2 is not valid.  My question is what is a good way to do this?  I want my original list2, but without {"def",2}.  Everything I can think of is pretty messy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way will be to pre-process `sel` before using it with `Pick` e.g.:

```
sel = sel /. {} -> {-1} // Flatten // Sign;
```

Here I'm assuming the integers in `sel` will always be positive since you say it's from a `Position` call.

```
Pick[list2, sel, 1]
```

> ```
> {{"abc", 1}, {"ghi", 3}, {"jkl", 4}, {"mno", 5}}
> ```

Comment: That works perfectly.  I had assumed (incorrectly) that the problem with using list2 was that sel didn't have pairs of values.  I didn't realize the empty list was causing the problem.  Why didn't that cause a problem with list1?

Answer (score 6):

```
list2[[Flatten[Position[sel, {_}]]]]

(*{{"abc", 1}, {"ghi", 3}, {"jkl", 4}, {"mno", 5}}*)
```

or simply:

```
list2 ~Extract~ Position[sel, {_}]     (* thanks to  Mr.Wizard*)

 (*{{"abc", 1}, {"ghi", 3}, {"jkl", 4}, {"mno", 5}}*)
```

Comment: I forgot that the question wasn't really how to make `Pick` work but how to perform this operation. +1  FWIW this is a little cleaner: `list2 ~Extract~ Position[sel, {_}]`

Comment: Great. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I covered this to some degree in my answer to: [Plot columns of table if some condition is fulfilled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/plot-columns-of-table-if-some-condition-is-fulfilled/11787#11787).

You should be aware that the behavior of `Pick` that causes your error is also one of its most powerful attributes.  It can handle arbitrary expression structure:

```
Pick[
 foo[a, bar[b, baz[c, d], e]],
 foo[r, bar[q, baz[q, r], r]],
 q
]
```

> ```
> foo[bar[b, baz[c]]]
> ```

The heads of the selection expression may be `List` even if the the heads of the primary expression are not:

```
Pick[
 foo[a, bar[b, baz[c, d], e]],
 {r, {q, {q, r}, r}},
 q
]
```

> ```
> foo[bar[b, baz[c]]]
> ```

I illustrate this only in case you (or other readers) think that the behavior of `Pick` is a bug.

The solution shown in my linked answer is essentially the same as RunnyKine's above, except that I prefer to resolve the selection expression to `True` and `False` directly.  For your example:

```
Pick[list2, MatchQ[{_}] /@ sel]
```

> ```
> {{"abc", 1}, {"ghi", 3}, {"jkl", 4}, {"mno", 5}}
> ```

Or if you do not have the version 10 operator form of `MatchQ`:

```
Pick[list2, MatchQ[#, {_}] & /@ sel]
```

Comment: Thanks - that also helps me better tie together the operator form and the "traditional" form.  Also Pick does not work as I had expected it to, thanks for explaining.