# Evaluating function only when its optional argument is numeric

Tags: numerical-integration, options, optional-arguments

I want to have the argument 'a' for myf2 in form of optional argument, but at the same time I need to evaluate the function only if 'a' is Numeric, see also  [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29945/nonlinearmodelfit-with-ndsolve).

```
Options[myf2] = {"a" -> 1};
myf2[b_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{y, x, a},
   a = OptionValue["a"];
   If[NumericQ[a], First[y /.NDSolve[{a y'[x] == b y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
       y, {x, 0, 30}]][10]]
   ];

datamyf2 = {#, myf2[1, #] + 0.01 RandomReal[]}&/@Range[0.5, 1.5,0.1]

model = NonlinearModelFit[datamyf2, myf2[b, "a" -> a], b, a]
```

When I tried to add the NumericQ test for 'a' in myf2, the problem is that it returns Null upon evaluating with symbol 'y' {myf2[1, "a" -> y]}, instead of leaving it unevaluated at all (as for the case when 'a' was specified as regular argument with a_?NumericQ)

How can I than specify that it should have numeric value for 'a' in the option?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good reason why you want `a` to be an optional argument? At least in your example it doesn't look optional to me.

Comment: I posted an example function, but in real application I'm using quite many optional arguments in a physical simulation function. In that case optional arguments are very handy, see i.e. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html)

Comment: I'm still not convinced by this approach. I would rather define different parameter sets (e.g. as lists of replacement rules) and pass these sets to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept!  However, I always recommend that users wait 24-hours before selecting an answer so as to give everyone around the world a chance to reply before a question appears concluded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question appears to be about [Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingOptions.html), not optional arguments.  While it is true that `OptionsPattern[]` is a form of optional argument that is not typically how options themselves are described.  *Edit: I see that the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) refers to options as "named optional arguments" so I guess my understanding of convention was incorrect.*

The meat of your question seems to be how to check an option value according to a pattern and return your expression (function call) unevaluated if it does not pass.  You can do this with a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) on the right-hand side of the definition:

```
Options[fn] = {"a" -> 1};

fn[b_?NumericQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  stuff[OptionValue["a"], b] /; NumericQ @ OptionValue["a"]

fn[3.5]
fn[3.5, "a" -> 7]
fn[3.5, "a" -> y]
```

> ```
> stuff[1, 3.5]
>
> stuff[7, 3.5]
>
> fn[3.5, "a" -> y]
> ```

Note that `opts :` was not needed here as [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionValue.html) is being used rather than e.g. [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html).

You could also make use of [sharing between a condition and function body](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html#123) for more complicated tests or simply to avoid having to use `OptionValue["a"]` twice. (See mid-way through [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching/1852#1852) for an explanation of this behavior.)

```
ClearAll[fn]

Options[fn] = {"a" -> 1};

fn[b_?NumericQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{a = OptionValue["a"]}, stuff[a, b] /; NumericQ[a]]

fn[3.5]
fn[3.5, "a" -> 7]
fn[3.5, "a" -> y]
```

> ```
> stuff[1, 3.5]
>
> stuff[7, 3.5]
>
> fn[3.5, "a" -> y]
> ```