# How do I use a while-loop to find the gain of a transfer function's limit?

Tags: broken-code

At the moment I can find the limit of my transfer function as follows:

```
(5 4001.6`)/(5 4001.6` + (4 + s) (200 + s)) /. s -> 0
```

This works as I would expect and provides a final value of 0.961553
In this example my value of gain, k, is 4001.6`
so re-writing the expression for arbitrary k would give:

```
   (5 k)/(5k + (4 + s) (200 + s)) /. s -> 0
```

I want to find a value of k that makes the result 0.95.
To do this I was thinking about using a while loop.

I thought the while loop could start with k=1, compute the limit, test to see if less than 0.95, and if not increment k by one, and perform the test again, until the correct value of k is found:

This is what I have tried:

```
    k = 1; While[(5 k)/(5 k + (4 + s) (200 + s)) /. s < 0.95, k++]
```

However I get the error:
"ReplaceAll::reps: {s<=0.95} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>"

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(... /. s -> 0) < 0.95`? The error message is telling you that you forgot a `->`.

Comment: Ah, I think Michael has a better handle on your particular intent.  Nevertheless consider reading: [(1835)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121) for some examples.

Comment: By the way: `FindRoot[0.95 == (5 k)/(5 k + (4 + s) (200 + s)) /. s -> 0, {k, 4000}]` Out: `{k -> 3040.}`

Comment: FWIW, Control`StaticGains[TransferFunctionModel[(5 k)/(5 k + (4 + s) (200 + s)), s]] will compute the steady-state gains.

Comment: There are easier ways to do this, but I am now confused about your TransferFunction. This can't be an actual transfer function. closed loop basic TF is   $\frac{k H(s)}{1+ k H(s)}$ and what you do next is use RootLocusPlot to see where it crosses the $s$ axis for specific $k$. It is easy now to make a manipulate which varies $k$ and see which values causes it to become unstable.

Comment: @Nasser this is just kH(s) [OL response] and by varying k and bode plotting the impulse response (response to a dirac delta function) we can see where the poles & zeros lie. It is an approximation of the CL system -> see "http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~covic/sctrl_da.PDF" for details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to code the numerical solver loop yourself, Mathematica has great built in functions. In the comments, @Mr.Wizard suggested `FindRoot`, but `Solve` may be easier for you:

```
Solve[((5 k)/(5 k + (4 + s) (200 + s)) /. s -> 0) == .95, k]

{{k -> 3040.}}
```