# Use of StringExpression as argument

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Is it possible to use a StringExpression as a pattern for an argument? I.E. something like

```
foo[chars__~~ WordCharacter.. ~~ num:NumberString] := {chars, num};
```

At the moment, I'm using a somewhat more convoluted function like

```
bar[str_String /; StringMatchQ[str, chars__~~ WordCharacter.. ~~ num:NumberString]] := 
StringCases[str,
     chars__~~ WordCharacter.. ~~ num:NumberString :> {chars, num}][[1]];
```

Comment: Would you describe your use case a bit?  My present answer assumes that you want the entire definition to not match if the string pattern does not match.  It is appropriate if you are blending string and non-string arguments.  However, if you are only operating on strings there may be another syntax that you find more convenient.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The case I'm working with at the moment involves converting a string that contains a specific character sequence into a list of two strings, each of which contains the 2 halves of the string with one being the reverse of the other. In my case, it is simple to solve using a `StringSplit` and a rule, but I plan on using a fair bit of string manipulation (Splitting things into different chunks and reordering/manipulating them in different ways), and was hoping there was a very simple way to accomplish things like this.

Comment: If you could give an example of your more complex manipulation, preferably in a new question, I'd be happy to try my hand at making it more convenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use string patterns directly as they are distinct from normal expression patterns, and need to be to prevent ambiguity.

You can however eliminate the double pattern matching by using the shared-body syntax of `With` and `Condition` I described in the middle of my answer to [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching/1852#1852):

```
foo[s_String] :=
  With[{res = StringCases[s, rule]},
    res /; res =!= {}
  ]
```

where `rule` is your pattern and replacement rule.  Note that if the pattern is not matched and `StringCases` returns `{}` *Mathematica* will act as if the entire definition did not match, apart from any side-effects induced during the trial evaluation.