# Simplifying expression with patterns (Replace)

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

**Q1**:

I need to simplify some algebraic expression, according to particular pattern, namely:

\begin{equation*}
x^m = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if } m \text{ is even} \\
x & \text{if } m \text{ is odd}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

for example:

$$
a x^3 + b x y-c x^7 y^2
$$
should be simplified to
$$
ax + bxy - cxy^2
$$
I need something like:

```
a x^3 + b x y - c x^7 y^2 /.{x^_ -> ... }
```

but, that will recognize the parity of the each power in the expression.

**Q2**:

How one can get only one term in the sum? For example, in the example there are three terms

$$
a x^3, \ b x y, \ -c x^7 y^2
$$

is there any possibility to decompose the full expression to

```
A = {a x^3, b x y, - c x^7 y^2}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = a x^3 + b x y - c x^7 y^2;

expr /. {x_^m_ /; EvenQ[m] :> 1, x_^m_ /; OddQ[m] :> x}
```

> ```
> a x - c x + b x y
> ```

```
List @@ expr
```

> ```
> {a x^3, b x y, -c x^7 y^2}
> ```

Be warned that `Replace` etc. can be fragile for mathematical manipulation.

As Pinguin Dirk noted I think you wanted matching for literal `x`; in that case you could use `x` in place of each `x_` pattern in my replacement rules:

```
expr /. {x^m_ /; EvenQ[m] :> 1, x^m_ /; OddQ[m] :> x}
```

> ```
> a x + b x y - c x y^2
> ```

Also, I used a longer form with [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) rather [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html), because I think the former is often easier to use for mathematical conditions.  See this for more:

- [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Comment: I understand the difference between "x" and "x_", but the last option also applies to ALL powers in the expression. How I can restrict to only particular monomials? (I do multi-dim Taylor expansion and should pick only particular variables from the expansion).

Comment: I added my variation to the comments below Pinguin Dirk's answer.  Also, thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way, replacing only if `m` is an integer:

```
expr /. {x^m_Integer :> x^Mod[m, 2]}
```

> `a x + b x y - c x y^2`

Note I am assuming that `x` is taken literally (we only match for `x`)

As for the question in the comments, a possible way would be to condition on the pattern, as Mr. Wizard does (in a similar way):

```
expr /. {patt_^m_Integer :> patt^Mod[m, 2] /; MemberQ[{x1, x2}, patt]}
```

where `{x1,x2}` are the bases you want to modify (I am using `patt` instead of `x` as the name of the pattern, to avoid confusion)

or also, as Mr. Wizard points out in the comments:

```
expr /. (x : x1 | x2 | x3)^m_Integer :> x^Mod[m, 2]
```

Comment: +1 for noting my oversight.  You could add `m_Integer` to make this more robust.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: thanks - and edited!

Comment: Thanks! And if there are more than one variable "x" (assume x1, x2, x3, and so on)? Needed something like:

expr /. {x*^m_Integer :> x*^Mod[m, 2]}, where "*" (star) is a linux-type expression for all possible values. (x* -> x1, x2, x3....)

just to avoid writing: /. {x1^m_Integer :> x1^Mod[m, 2],x2^m_Integer :> x2^Mod[m, 2], .... }

Comment: I tried with "x_", but it replace ALL variables with powers and I want only particular variables (x1,x2,x3..).

Comment: @AndrewKor: see the edit

Comment: @Pinguin Dirk, Perfect! Thanks a lot! I believe that one day, I will become a Math. professional like you guys :)

Comment: @AndrewKor You could also use `Alternatives` rather than `MemberQ`: `expr /. (x : x1 | x2 | x3)^m_Integer :> x^Mod[m, 2]`

Comment: thanks for another idea, @Mr.Wizard. Added!

Answer (score 3):

A little bit more compact answer to Q1

```
expr /. {_^_?EvenQ :> 1, x_^_?OddQ :> x}
```

> ```
> a x - c x + b x y
> ```

Comment: +1 for brevity :-)  I chose `Condition` as I think it is a bit more general for mathematical conditions.

Comment: looking at the example, I guess he wants the pattern to match for `x` only, not for `x_` (i.e. `x`, `y`,...), or am I mistaken? (I am not quite sure)

Comment: You can make this shorter: `expr /. {_^_?EvenQ :> 1, x_^_?OddQ :> x}` or by Pinguin Dirk's reading: `expr /. {x^_?EvenQ -> 1, x^_?OddQ -> x}`