# Pattern test: _Integer vs _?IntegerQ

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

While checking out the different pattern replacement methods in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/simplifying-expression-with-patterns-replace), I have a query regarding the basic difference between the following two replacements:

```
 expr = a x^3 + b x y - c x^7 y^2;
 expr /. {x^m_Integer :> x^Mod[m, 2]}
 expr /. {x^m_?Integer :> x^Mod[m, 2]}
```

The first replacement works as expected, but the second replacement does not do anything. What is happening in the second one. Also, another code to effect the desired replacement is

```
expr /. {x^_?EvenQ -> 1, x^_?OddQ -> x}
```

which contains "?" after an underscore.

Any help to solve this confusion will be appreciated.

Comment: you can use `expr /. {x^m_?IntegerQ :> x^Mod[m, 2]}`

Comment: see [tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html)

Comment: @kglr Thanks for the solution and the link. Could you kindly illustrate the difference between _Integer and _?IntegerQ ?  Another one is "_Integer?" mentioned in the following link discussing partly my doubts.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/assessing-argument-type-in-set-delayed-function-definitions

Comment: If you use the `_?func` pattern then `func` can be any function at all. Any function you can think of. `_head` is a shorthand for the pattern `head[___]`. A pattern that doesn't involve arbitrary black box functions can be optimized in ways that it couldn't if it had to evaluate arbitrary functions on each possible match. Don't use `_?func` unless you have to.

Comment: `m_?Integer` is incorrect. Did you mean `IntegerQ`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I was using m_?Integer which was not correct.
kglr already suggested m_?IntegerQ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html).

`x_?test` matches if `test[x]` is `True`. It is equivalent to `x_ /; test[x]` (see [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)).

`x_symbol` matches if `Head[x]` is `symbol`.

`m_?Integer` makes no sense because `Integer` is not a function that returns `True` or `False`.  `m_?IntegerQ` is valid and works. See [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html) and [`IntegerQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerQ.html).

`_Integer` and `_?IntegerQ` are very similar, but there are some important differences:

`_Integer` is faster than `_?IntegerQ`:

```
list = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomInteger[1000, 1000000];

fun1[_Integer] := "x";
fun2[_?IntegerQ] := "x";

fun1 /@ list; // Timing
(* {0.23702, Null} *)

fun2 /@ list; // Timing
(* {0.376331, Null} *)
```

But `_Integer` also matches expressions which are not really integers, such as `Integer["abc"]`.

The same applies to other, similarly named functions as well.

`_?GraphQ` and `_Graph` are not the same. `_?AssociationQ` and `_Association` are not the same. This is because there are expressions with the head `Association` that are not atomic associations.

```
expr = Association[123]
(* Association[123] *)

MatchQ[expr, _Association]
(* True *)

MatchQ[expr, _?AssociationQ]
(* False *)
```

In these cases, one usually needs the pattern `_?AssociationQ`. Then the expression will work with functions like `Lookup`, `KeyTake`, etc.

There is even use for `_Association?AssociationQ`. This pattern is faster to reject non-associations than `_?AssociationQ`, but it is otherwise functionally equivalent.

Comment: Are _?EvenQ and _Even equivalent?
 The code
expr /. {x^_Even -> 1, x^_Odd -> x} does not work.

Comment: @MarkRobinson I don't follow your thinking ... as I said, `_Even` matches expressions with the head `Even`. That symbol has no built-in meaning. Why would you even try to use it? Why do you think it has any connection to `EvenQ`?  If something was not clear in my explanation, please ask.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `_Integer` and `_?IntegerQ` are not fully equivalent - e.g. for `Integer["a"]`, only the former matches. While this is admittedly a rather contrived example, I encountered this issue a few times with `Symbol[…]` (I was using `_Symbol` to get all symbols in the expression, which failed due to the above)

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks! You're right, it's the same situation as with `Association`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the clearly explained and to the point answer and illustrating the equivalence with condition. I now understand it to a good extent.

Comment: MatchQ["abc", x_Integer] as well as MatchQ["a", x_Integer] give both False in Mathematica 13.3.1. A better example today would be: MatchQ[Integer[x], _Integer] (* True; False for x_?IntegerQ *)