# Function with only integer arguments

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a function which can take only integer arguments and have found two ways to do the same :

```
func1[n_Integer, m_Integer] := If[n==m,0,n-m]
func2[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] := If[n==m,0,n-m]
```

I have also read about the difference between the two : [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198204/pattern-test-integer-vs-integerq). Both of the above ways ensure that the functions are not evaluated if the argument is not having a `Head` as `Integers`.

However, I would like the functions to return `0` if the arguments are not integers instead of being unevaluated. One way to do this would be using a nested-if (not sure about the terminology in `Mathematica`) :

```
func3[n_, m_] := 
 If[IntegerQ[n] && IntegerQ[m], If[n == m, 1, n - m], 0]
```

Is there any way other than using the above to achieve the same result? Also, if I use `func1` and `func2` in an integral etc such that their arguments are `[5,5.2]` then am I going to receive any warning of the non-evaluation or that particular value is just going to be skipped?

Comment: Is there any need for the `If` statement?  Adapting the answer by bill s, maybe: `f[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] := n-m; f[n_, m_] := 0; f[n_?IntegerQ, n_?IntegerQ] := 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the definition of your function to include all inputs:

```
func2[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] := If[n==m,0,n-m]
func2[n_, m_] := 0
```

Now when you input n and m integers the top definition applies, when n or m are not integers, the bottom applies. Thus func2[4, 7] is -3 while func2[54., 32] is 0. You could do the same for func1.

Comment: Nice. Before I accept this as an answer, can you also point out any pitfalls of this method? Any implementation I should be careful about? Which method is better : nested-if or extending the definition ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a pitfall, but you might want to note that func2[n_,m_] as above evaluates for symbols as well as numbers. If you don't want this, then you can extend the idea to as many different definitions as make sense for your problem.

Comment: To avoid premature evaluation, use `func2[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] := n - m; 
func2[n_, m_?(NumericQ[#] && ! IntegerQ[#] &)] = 0; 
func2[n_?(NumericQ[#] && ! IntegerQ[#] &), m_] = 0;`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. These helped a lot. :)