# Initialize table in a Module but Break if criteria not met

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I am initializing a table inside a function as follows:

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{RM = Table[a1+a2+a3+i1, {i1, 1, 10}]}, Plus@@RM]
```

I am calling the function `f` multiple times with different values of `a1, a2, a3` and want the function to exit, if `300<a1+a2+a3+i1<500`

How can I do it elegantly by not initializing the table and later checking to proceed or `Break`?

This is what I have started to do, but could not go too far:

```
LL[a1_, a2_, a3_, x_] := 300 < a1+a2+a3+i1 < 500;
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{RM = Table[If[L[a1, a2, a3, i1]==True,L[a1, a2, a3, i1],
        Break[]] , {i1, 1, 10}]},Plus@@RM]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your own method can be refined into something useful:

```
f1[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{test, RM},
  test = If[300 < # < 500, #, Return[{}, Module]] &;
  RM = Table[test[a1 + a2 + a3 + i1], {i1, 1, 10}];
  Total @ RM
 ]
```

Now:

```
f1[100, 101, 102]
f1[1, 2, 3]
f1[100, 195, 200]
```

> ```
> 3085
>
> {}
>
> {}
> ```

Note that I used a special syntax of `Return` to exit without error.  I am assuming that you cannot simply test the end points of your `Table` range, but rather need to test every value generated by some function.  Otherwise use a condition as [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46182/121) did, in one formulation or another.

If you want the function to return unevaluated you can achieve it with two small modifications:

```
f2[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{test, RM},
  test = If[300 < # < 500, #, Return[{}, Table]] &;
  RM = Table[test[a1 + a2 + a3 + i1], {i1, 1, 10}];
  Total @ RM /; RM =!= {}
 ]

f2[100, 101, 102]
f2[1, 2, 3]
f2[100, 195, 200]
```

> ```
> 3085
>
> f2[1, 2, 3]
>
> f2[100, 195, 200]
> ```

Note that `Return` is changed to exit from `Table` rather than the entire `Module`.  Then a special form of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) is used.  See: [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching/1852#1852)

If failure to match is an uncommon event it is better to write the function to be faster in the common case where it does not exit or return unevaluated.  For that you would leave the test until after the `Table` is generated, e.g.:

```
f3[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{RM},
  RM = Table[a1 + a2 + a3 + i1, {i1, 1, 10}];
  Total @ RM /; 300 < Min[RM] && Max[RM] < 500
 ]
```

Speed comparison within a matching range:

```
Table[
 Do[fn[100, 100, x], {x, 100, 280, 0.01}] // Timing // First,
 {fn, {f1, f2, f3}}
]
```

> ```
> {0.374, 0.375, 0.249}
> ```

Comment: This is perfect for me!!

Comment: @brama Glad I could help.  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] /; (IntervalIntersection[Interval[{300, 500}], 
     Interval[a1 + a2 + a3 + {1, 10}]] === Interval[]) := 
 Module[{RM = Table[a1 + a2 + a3 + i1, {i1, 1, 10}]}, Plus@@ RM]
```

Is probably the most direct way to accomplish this. Called with non-satisfying values, it simply returns unevaluated.

Comment: Thanks, but the condition has the cell index `i1` as `300<a1+a2+a3+i1<500`. This is a simplified condition, but the original condition is much more complex

Comment: @brama: Ah, missed that in OP. Will adjust or delete, give me a moment...

Comment: @brama: OK - I think this does what you've asked for (completely misread OP first time). This only returns if no value of a1+a2+a3+i1 is in the range of 300 to 500. Frankly, I think it more convoluted than your idea of just adding an *If* to your function definition...

Comment: +1 for answering the question as written, but I'm guessing that brama cannot test only the end-points of the `Table` iterator.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - yes, I think perhaps a clarification of the "much more complex" condition in the OP is warranted. Thanks much for +...

Answer (score 0):

You can not "break" from a table like that, try something like this:

```
     i=0;
     First@Last@Reap[While[++i; !(300<a1+a2+a3+i1<500) && i<=10, Sow[result] ]
```

(your condition  and result are a bit vague in your question by the way.)

Also I'm assuming you want to keep the values computed up to the exit condition.

If you wanted to just discard everything then you can do:

```
    Catch[Table[ If[!condition, Throw[{}], value], {i, 10}]]
```