# Placement of pattern matching rules in functions

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Is there any difference at all between

```
f[x_Integer /; x >= 0] := x + 1;
f[x_Integer] := x - 1;
f[x_] := Null;
```

and

```
f[x_Integer] := x + 1 /; x >= 0;
f[x_Integer] := x - 1;
f[x_] := Null;
```

The output is identical in both the cases.  Even if there is no technical difference, is it common practice to adhere one and avoid the other?

Comment: They are not the same. With the pattern on the right, the right side will evaluate anything up to the rule-constrained piece, while with the rule in the argument body, that won't happen. Try, e.g., changing the body of your example to have a prepended print: `(Print["Hi"];...)`, then call each with -1 - the first will return unevaluated, the second evaluates the print. In your specific example, the end result is the same.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Very informative link! +1

Comment: @rasher I believe you are mistaken.  The only time (that I recall) the body should be evaluating is when `Condition` is used inside `With` or `Module`. (As I mention [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1852/121).)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: You are correct - I doofused and forgot to put parenthesis around compound statement...DOH!