# Can a pattern examine all partitions of a sequence?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, argument-patterns

Say I have a list: `{a, b, c, d}`. I'd like to check that the list has some partition, say {{a, b, c}, {d}} such that all the elements of the partition satisfy a predicate (or match a pattern).  So in this case, both {a, b, c} and {d} would match.  Can this be done purely with patterns?  I notice that all sequence patterns with predicates apply only to individual elements of the sequence.

More concrete example:

I have --

```
formQ[x___] := (listQ[x] == True) || (atomQ[x] == True)
listQ[token["("], middle, token[")"]] := (formQ[middle] == True)
atomQ[x_token] := x =!= token["("]  && x =!= token[")"]
```

(of course instead of middle I'd have this pattern I'm looking for)

So for example,

```
listQ[token["("], token["3"], token[")"]] == True
listQ[token["("], token["3"], token["("], token[")"], token[")"]] == True
formQ[token["3"]] == True
formQ[token["("], token[")"]] == True
formQ[token["("], token[")"], token["3"]] == False
```

Basically I'm messing around with a scheme-like parser... I already have the tokenizer working, and I'm seeing if I can recognize elements like "forms" and "lists" and "atoms".

A form is something like "(3 4 5)" or "( ( ) ( 5 ) )" but not "( ) )" or "3 4" or "3 ( ) 4".  The reason I need to be able to match multiple forms is that a list can contain multiple atoms or sublists, all of which are forms.

**EDIT:** ReplaceRepeated is helpful, working from the inside out, but doesn't answer the question.

```
readTokens[x_String] := Map[token, StringCases[x, 
    RegularExpression[" *(\\(|\\)|[^ \\(\\)]+) *"] -> "$1"]]
atomQ[x_token] := x =!= token["("]  && x =!= token[")"]
listQ[x___] := ReplaceRepeated[{x}, {a___, token["("], q___?atomQ, token[")"], 
    b___} :> {a, b}]  == {}
```

So we have

```
listQ @@ readTokens["((a b c)))"] == False
listQ @@ readTokens["((a b c))"] == True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the intent correctly, then the following definitions should recognize valid forms:

```
ClearAll[formQ, listQ, atomQ, sequenceQ]

formQ[x___] := listQ[x] || atomQ[x]

atomQ[token[Except["("|")"]]] := True
atomQ[___] := False

listQ[token["("], x___, token[")"]] := sequenceQ[x]
listQ[___] := False

sequenceQ[] := True
sequenceQ[x__ /; formQ[x], y___ /; sequenceQ[y]] := True
sequenceQ[__] := False
```

The definitions of `formQ` and `atomQ` are essentially unchanged, with some minor tweaks for failure cases.

The main change is to the definition of `listQ`.  A new helper function, `sequenceQ` has been introduced.  Its purpose is to recognize a (possibly empty) sequence of valid forms.  `sequenceQ` performs the "partitioning" requested in the question.  It will extract a leading valid non-empty form, and then verify that what remains is a valid sequence.  `Condition` (`/;`) is used in place of `PatternTest` (`?`) since, as noted in the question, the latter operates upon individual matched sequence elements instead of the whole matched sequence.

**Be Careful Not To Defeat Back-Tracking**

There is a subtlety in this definition.  It is crucially important that the `formQ` and `sequenceQ` checks appear within the pattern itself and not within the body of the definition -- the following will not work:

```
(* do not do this! it disables back-tracking *)
sequenceQ[x__, y___] := formQ[x] && sequenceQ[y]
```

When the conditions appear in the pattern, the pattern matcher will back-track if the tests fail.  In the absence of those tests, the pattern matcher will think that there is no need to back-track since it has found a successful match and gone ahead to execute the body of the definition.

It would be acceptable to move the condition onto the right-hand side like this:

```
(* this will work *)
sequenceQ[x__, y___] := True /; formQ[x] && sequenceQ[y]
```

On the face of it, the construction `True /; ...` might seem to be an awkward and unnecessary rephrasing of the previous expression.  But do not be fooled: the meaning is quite different.  Conditions (`/;`) are integrated into the pattern matching process, but tests in the main definition body are not.

Conditions of this form are often expressed thus:

```
(* this will work too *)
sequenceQ[x__, y___] /; formQ[x] && sequenceQ[y] := True

(* and so will this *)
sequenceQ[x__ /; formQ[x], y___ /; sequenceQ[y]] := True
```

Choose the form that suits your taste.

**What About Back-Tracking In The Other Definitions?**

`formQ` and `listQ` perform checks in their definition bodies in opposition to the advice just given.  I left them that way for continuity from the original question.  It so happens that those definitions do not require internal back-tracking to function correctly.  In recognizers, I recommend adopting a policy of putting recognition checks in pattern conditions as a matter of course.  Under such a policy, tests appear in definition bodies only when explicit back-tracking "cuts" are desired.

The definitions can be made to conform to this suggestion like this:

```
ClearAll[formQ, listQ, atomQ, sequenceQ]

formQ[x___] /; listQ[x] || atomQ[x] := True
formQ[___] := False

listQ[token["("], x___, token[")"]] /; sequenceQ[x] := True
listQ[___] := False

sequenceQ[] := True
sequenceQ[x__, y___] /; formQ[x] && sequenceQ[y] := True
sequenceQ[__] := False

atomQ[token[Except["("|")"]]] := True
atomQ[___] := False
```

**Test Cases**

All of the following test cases evaluate to `True`:

```
True === atomQ[token["3"]]
True === listQ[token["("], token["3"], token[")"]]
True === listQ[token["("], token["3"], token["("], token[")"], token[")"]]
True === formQ[token["3"]]
True === formQ[token["("], token[")"]]
True === formQ[token["("], token["("], token["("], token[")"], token[")"], token[")"]]
True === formQ[token["("], token["("], token[")"], token["("], token[")"], token[")"]]

False === formQ[token["("]]
False === formQ[token["("], token[")"], token["3"]]
False === formQ[token["("], token["1"], token["2"]]
False === formQ[token["1"], token["2"]]
False === atomQ[token["1"], token["2"]]
False === atomQ[]
False === listQ[]
False === formQ[]
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting. I realize now that most of the intent behind my question was to figure out how to use patterns to do backtracking. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this actually does backtrack -- I defined a simpler version of this where a valid form is either ("blue") or ("green") or ("blue", "green") or ("green", "red") and asked whether ("blue", "green", "red") was a valid sequence.  If it had insisted on matching "blue" (and possibly "green") and not backtracking, it would have seen "red" and returned False.  But it returned True.

Answer (score 3):

I have trouble following your example (in the comment) so I shall attempt to answer this question generically.  If you can give a few examples of actual input and output that you expect from `listQ` I shall attempt to implement it.

Individual elements of of pattern sequence are tested when you use [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), but the entire sequence can be easily tested if you use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html).  See:

- [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Considering your target partition `{{a, b, c}, {d}}` observe:

```
Replace[
 {7, 2, 4, 3},
 {x__, y__?OddQ} /; Plus[x] == 13 :> {{x}, {y}}
]
```

> ```
> {{7, 2, 4}, {3}}
> ```

This checks to see that the sum of the sequence of elements bound to `x` is 13, and that any remaining elements individually pass `OddQ`.  Additional examples of match and non-match of this pattern:

```
Replace[
 {5, 3, 5, 7, 1},
 {x__, y__?OddQ} /; Plus[x] == 13 :> {{x}, {y}}
]
```

> ```
> {{5, 3, 5}, {7, 1}}  (* match and replace *)
> ```

```
Replace[
 {5, 3, 5, 2, 2},
 {x__, y__?OddQ} /; Plus[x] == 13 :> {{x}, {y}}
]
```

> ```
> {5, 3, 5, 2, 2}  (* no match, no replace *)
> ```

---

You provided an additional example:

> As a simplified example let's say I want a function to return True every time it sees a list of the form {a, b, c, ...} where it can break the list into groups that add up to 13.  So it would work with {13, 13} or {10, 3, 13} or even {10, 3, 10, 3}, but not {13, 5, 13}.

This case is tricky because *naming* a pattern forces any appearances of that pattern to match each other.  Therefore if you use a [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) pattern like `{(x__ /; Plus[x] == 13) ..}` it will match `{10, 3, 10, 3}` since the partitions are identical, but it will *not* match `{10, 3, 13}` because the partitions would be different from each other.   A solution is recursion, which can even be done within patterns, though it is arguable that this is not  a self-contained pattern:

```
p1 = {x__ /; +x == 13, y___} /; MatchQ[{y}, p1 | {}];

MatchQ[
 {10, 3, 10, 3, 13, 2, 4, 7},
 p1
]
```

> True

(`+x` is simply shorthand for `Plus[x]`.)

Comment: @epylar Please used the **edit** link under your question to add detail.   Thank you.

Comment: As a simplified example let's say I want a function to return True every time it sees a list of the form {a, b, c, ...} where it can break the list into groups that add up to 13.  So it would work with {13, 13} or {10, 3, 13} or even {10, 3, 10, 3}, but not {13, 5, 13}.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've added more detail.

Comment: @epylar The problem in your first comment is actually rather tricky.  I am trying to remember the right approach to that.

Comment: Obviously it can be done without patterns, but if there is a way to do it with patterns, it seems worth knowing.  Also if you are allowed to be "greedy" -- that if you find a 10 and a 3 you're allowed to use that as a 13, and then only concern yourself with the rest of the list, you could use repeated replace.

Comment: @epylar Yes, recursion "eating" from left to right seems like the natural approach but it is not purely pattern-based.  I think I vaguely remember someone posting a solution but I cannot recall it now.

Comment: @epylar I made an update to include this.  I do not know if you will find it satisfying.  I am very tired right now but I shall return to your updated parser example at a later time, if someone else has not already satisfactorily addressed it by then.