# How to use Strings and Functions With Conditions

Tags: concatenation

Very new to Mathematica so this might be really simple.

I have the function

```
pow[x_,r_]:= x^r
```

where r is rational due to

```
rationalQ[r_] := IntegerQ[Numerator[r]] && IntegerQ[Denominator[r]]
```

I'm trying to use conditions so that when I test pow[0,0] where x=0 and r=0, the output uses the string "undefined" instead of Indeterminate.

Any idea how it works?

Comment: you can simply do `pow[0,0]="undefined"`

Comment: thanks for the help! so I have a second case where I'm still using the same function and r is still rational, except this time I have to set up a condition where I make it so that when x is any number except 0 and r=0, the output should be 1. How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this,

```
pow[x_,r_?rationalQ]:= x^r
pow[___] := "Undefined"
```

These function definitions are called [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) in *Mahtematica*, and they are applied in order of increasing generality.

So what is going on here, if you evaluate `pow` with two variables, **and** the second variable gives `True` when fed to `rationalQ`, then that definition is used.  Otherwise the evaluator will continue to look for other matching patterns.  The `pow[___]` is the most general pattern, and so anything that doesn't match the first pattern will match it.

For more information, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1852/9490.

Comment: thanks so much, this is really helpful. I already posted a comment on my second case but I figured I'd comment it here too so you get the notification? I have a second case where I'm still using the same function and r is still rational, except this time I have to set up a condition where I make it so that when x is any number except 0 and r=0, the output should be 1. How am I supposed to set up the condition?