# The difference between ? and /;

Tags: list-manipulation

I can do the following

```
Cases[Range@10, x_ /; OddQ[x]]
```

But why cannot I do `x_?OddQ[x]` instead of `_?OddQ` in the following?

```
Cases[Range@10, x_ ? OddQ[x]]
```

Generally speaking, I am confused with using `?` and `/;`.

## Edit

After reading the existing comments and answer, I understood now that `?` needs function. However, it still confused me, when we prefer  `?` to `/;` and vice versa?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Did you read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)?  `?` must be followed by a function and `OddQ[x]` is not a function. This question feels a bit like "I can compute a sum with `Sum`, but why can't I compute a sum with `Product`?"

Comment: [PatternTest >> Properties and relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html): _**"PatternTest applies test functions to patterns, which need not have names"**_  and  _**"Condition evaluates a Boolean expression on named parts of a pattern"**_

Comment: possible duplicate: [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/125)

Comment: @kglr: Thank you. It is a duplicate by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you should use `OddQ[x]`

```
Cases[Range@10, x_?(x \[Function] OddQ[x])]
```

### Edit

Thanks to the comment for pointing it out, the `x` in `(x \[Function] OddQ[x])` is *irrelevant* to the first `x`, you can replace it with any other vars.

In other words, `(x \[Function] f[x])` == `Function[x,f[x]]` == `f[#]&` == `f`

Comment: This is basically identical to what @Montevideo showed (use a pure function), but I find this version to be potentially misleading: you use `x` for two entire separate an unrelated purposes. Someone who is already confused about the difference between `/;` and `?` could very well end up being even more confused, and believing that there is some connection between those two `x`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this to solve this problem:

```
Cases[Range@10, x_?(OddQ[#] &)]

Cases[Range@10, x_?(OddQ)]
```

You may have confused pattern matching and conditional judgment functions.

Comment: `(OddQ[#] &)` is `OddQ` , nearly no difference.

Comment: `Cases[Range[10], _?OddQ]`