# What does Dash Question mark do?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

This is an example I'm reading that picks out the Primes, but I don't quite see how the _?  works. I haven't seen it before and can't find it in Help.

```
Cases[Range[500], _?PrimeQ]
```

Comment: `?` in this context is [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), and `_` is an ordinary [`Blank[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html). `_?f` is a pattern that matches any `x` such that `f[x]` is `True`. (Note that you don't *have* to use `_`—you can use any pattern! E.g. `x_Integer?PrimeQ` matches any `Integer` that is prime and names the pattern `x`.)

Comment: I'd say it's properer to mark this post as duplicate of [_What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871).

Answer (score 5):

This is called conditional pattern-matching.

[image]

From [Professor Richard J. Gaylord's Wolfram Language Fundamentals Part One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-rnezxOCA8) at time 57:04

See also [using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching)

Here is the main page for documentation on conditional pattern matching  [PatternTest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)

To check/test the pattern before using it somewhere, use `MatchQ`

Comment: " easily found in the documentation." That is not the case. All other shorthands, such as /. , /; , __, etc, are indeed found, but _? cannot be found. If I am in error please give the link.

Comment: @cybervigilante  it is not me who said **easily found in the documentation** that is in the message generated automatically by the system when question is closed. So I have nothing to do with the message. You can ask new/separate question if you want about this.

Comment: My error. That was just a general reply to the sometime unhelpful administration, which I hurriedly mis-posted since I was annoyed at their attitude of closing down what I felt was a valid query. 

Comment: @cybervigilante no problem. If you want to complain about an issue related to administrative issue on this site, you can contact the admin or post question at meta site for Mathematica (link is above)

Comment: @cybervigilante Notice that, as mentioned by thorimur in comment above, `_?` is actually combination of two functions `Blank` and `PatternTest`. By searching the single `?` in document, you'll find `PatternTest`. When you see unknown shorthand in _Mathematica_, a easy way to find their full form is to use `//Hold//FullForm` e.g. `Cases[Range[500], _?PrimeQ] // Hold // FullForm`.