# Overloading second argument of CountryData

Tags: functions, curated-data

For convenience I'm trying to add an extra property to `CountryData`

```
Unprotect[CountryData];
CountryData[c_String, "MyProperty"] := 0; (* actually call to another function *)
Protect[CountryData];
```

But when using it I get:

```
CountryData["Greenland", "MyProperty"]
```

> CountryData::notprop: "!(\"\\"MyProperty\\"\") is not a known property for CountryData. Use CountryData[\"Properties\"] for a list of properties."

What's the right way to do this?

*There is high probability this is a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find how to do this, sorry in advance*

Comment: Tangentially related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2793/121

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a matter of rules ordering for `CountryData` definitions. You have to do something like this:

```
Unprotect[CountryData];
CountryData[c_String, "MyProperty"] := 0;
(*actually call to another function*)
DownValues[CountryData] = RotateRight[DownValues[CountryData]];
Protect[CountryData];
```

This reorders the definitions so that yours is at the top (or close to the top). Then:

```
CountryData["Greenland","MyProperty"]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @ssch Was glad to help. I think I've run into exactly such problem with `...Data` before. Also a good example of when manual rule reordering is really needed. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @Stefan Long experience... :-). This particular issue is covered in Mathematica book and also [David Wagner's book](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat) on Mathematica programming.