# Search words based of word pronunciation?

Tags: dictionary, word-cloud

Basically the opposite of the following [Find a word's linguistic pronunciation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32148/find-a-words-linguistic-pronunciation)

I had thought of forming my own dictionary but it doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: opposite of this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordData.html

Comment: Aahhh, you mean that you have the pronunciation of a word and you want to search for the words with similar pronunciation!  Yes, I think you should probably make your own dictionary.  Failing that, search the online Wolfram documentation for "homophones" (and similar terms) you might find something useful in the resource repository.

Comment: Are you looking to search for words using the IPA as inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that does not rely on the International Phonetic Alphabet or building a dictionary and makes use of built-in functions

```
wordSoundsLike[wordPronounciation_String] :=
 Module[
  {
   wordSpokenPronounciation = SpeechSynthesize[wordPronounciation],
   closestWordFunction = Nearest[DictionaryLookup[]],
   wordApproximation
   },
  wordApproximation = SpeechRecognize[wordSpokenPronounciation];
  closestWordFunction[wordApproximation]
  ];
```

It works suprisingly well. On my limited test set `SpeechRecognize` is the weak point as `SpeechSynthesize` does a pretty good job. (eg `AudioPlay@SpeechSynthesize@"wustersher saws"`)

### Examples

---

On "easy" words:

```
wordSoundsLike["eksplane"] (*Explain*)
```

> {**"explain"**}

```
wordSoundsLike["kohmodeetea"] (*Commodity*)
```

> {**"commodity"**}

---

On "ambiguous" words

```
wordSoundsLike["fewsha"] (*Fuchsia*)
```

> {"Asia", "curia", "fascia", **"fuchsia"**, "fuse", "fused", "fusee", 
> "fuses", "fusing", "fusion", "fuss", "fussy", "fustian", "fusty", 
> "Julia", "Lucia", "Luria", "Musial", "music", "Nubia", "Russia", 
> "Susie"}

```
wordSoundsLike["indite"] (*Indict*)
```

> {**"indict"**, "indie", "indite", "innit"}

---

On "[impossible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwTT8YQFJDQ)" words ;)

```
wordSoundsLike["wustersher saws"] (*Worcestershire Sauce*)
```

> {"high-pressure", "statuesque", "thirstiness"}

```
wordSoundsLike["lester"] (*Leicester*)
```

> {"lest"}

---