# How can one manually change the rule ordering

Tags: core-language, variable-definitions

I have a function which has some general behavior, but that should act on some specific kinds of objects in some other way. I know that Mathematica is supposed to automatically order the rules so that the more specific rules are applied first. Nevertheless, I want to be sure that I can change the order manually in case Mathematica is not able to do this automatically in my case.

**edit:**
A simple example of such a situation where rule reordering takes place is (taken out of Leonid Shifrin's book, which I highly recommend)

```
In[1]:= Clear[f];
In[2]:= f[x_]:= Sin[x];
In[3]:= f[x_?EvenQ]:= x;
In[4]:= f[x_?OddQ]:= x^2;
In[5]:= {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[3/2], f[Newton]} 
Out[1]:= {1, 2, 9, 4, Sin[3/2], Sin[Newton]}
```

So the Sin definition takes place last even though it was defined first. So for example in this case is there a way to make the Sin always apply first without unsetting the other definitions? Or conversely to make sure a definition is used first even though it was declared last?

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Can we get a minimum example of the behavior you want to change?

Comment: The rules are given by `DownValues[f]`. Mathematica evaluates the rules in the order given there. You can change `DownValues` manually, e.g. `DownValues[f] = { stuff }` if you're not happy with how Mathematica ordered the rules automatically.

Comment: I edited, adding Jason B's request.

@LLlAMnYP is there a way to do this without knowing the existing definitions in advance? or maybe use Prepend?

Comment: It seems there is no general answer: [How is pattern specificity decided?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/5478)

Comment: Lior, I encourage you not to Accept an answer so quickly.  People often pass over questions with Accepted answers as they appear to be resolved.  I like to wait at least 24 hours to give everyone around the world a chance to see my question before Accepting an answer.  However it is your prerogative and you can Accept or change your Accept at any time.

Comment: I see that's a good point. In this case I won't take the credit back but in the future I'll remember that .

Comment: @LiorBlech that's fine, I'd rather see more interesting approaches than get a few extra internet points. You can unaccept and reaccept at any time.

Comment: @Carl, the "behaviour" is likely from the OP's British influence… ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### General

The definitions get reordered at definition-time by a part of the pattern matcher, that takes care of automatic rule reordering. It does so, based on relative generality of rules, *as far as it is able to determine that*. This is not always possible, so when it can't determine which of the two rules is more general, it appends the rules to `DownValues` (or `SubValues`, `UpValues`, etc.) in the order the definitions are given. This is described [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html). Some past discussions on this site, containing more information about that, can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-generally-match-unify-and-merge-patterns) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/how-is-pattern-specificity-decided).

#### Manipualations with `DownValues`

As mentioned in comments and the other answer, one general way to change the order of definitions is to manipulate `DownValues` directly, assigning to `DownValues[f]` the rules in the order you want. This technique has been described [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingValueLists.html), and also extensively in David Wagner's book (which is [available for free](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat)).

The most general way is indeed

```
DownValues[f] = {rules}
```

However, sometimes a more special form of rule rearrangement is handy: if you give a new definition, which you want to be tried first, but which you know for sure to be added last, you can do this:

```
f[...]:=your-new-definition;
DownValues[f] = RotateRight[DownValues[f]]
```

In which case, your definitions becomes the first, while all the other definitions maintain the same relative order as before. This trick has been discussed by Wagner in his book. Another example where this trick has been put to use, is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/overloading-second-argument-of-countrydata).

#### Using symbolic tags to fool the reordering system

This trick I haven't seen used by others, although I am sure I was not the only one to come up with it. Basically, you do something like this:

```
ClearAll[f, $tag];
f[x_] /; ($tag; True) := Sin[x];
f[x_?EvenQ] := x;
f[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
```

The pattern-matcher can no longer decide that the first rule is more general than the others, since it can't know what `$tag` is, until the code runs. In practice, `$tag` should have no value, and serves only to ensure that rules aren't reordered. It is also convenient since, if you no longer need such definition, you can simply do

```
DownValues[f] = DeleteCases[DownValues[f], def_/;!FreeQ[def, $tag]]
```

#### When it breaks

One other subtle point, that tends to be overlooked, is that definitions which don't contain patterns (underscores and other pattern-building blocks), are stored in a separate hash-table internally. In `DownValues` list, they always come first - since indeed, they are always more specific than those containing patterns. And no matter how you reorder `DownValues`, you can't bring those "down" the definitions list. For example:

```
 ClearAll[ff, $tag];
 ff[x_] /; ($tag; True) := Sin[x];
 ff[x_?EvenQ] := x;
 ff[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
 ff[0] = 0;
 ff[1] = 10;
```

Let's check now:

```
DownValues[ff]

(*

    {HoldPattern[ff[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[ff[1]] :> 10, 
     HoldPattern[ff[x_] /; ($tag; True)] :> Sin[x], 
     HoldPattern[ff[x_?EvenQ]] :> x, HoldPattern[ff[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}
*)
```

We can attempt to reorder manually:

```
 DownValues[ff] = DownValues[ff][[{3, 4, 5, 1, 2}]]
```

only to discover that this didn't work:

```
DownValues[ff]

(*

    {HoldPattern[ff[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[ff[1]] :> 10, 
     HoldPattern[ff[x_] /; ($tag; True)] :> Sin[x], 
     HoldPattern[ff[x_?EvenQ]] :> x, HoldPattern[ff[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}
*)
```

In some sense, this is good, because e.g. this makes standard memoization idiom `f[x_]:=f[x]=...` both possible and stable / robust. But this is something to keep in mind.

You can still make these definitions be the last by using the tag-trick:

```
ClearAll[ff, $tag, $tag1];
ff[x_] /; ($tag; True) := Sin[x];
ff[x_?EvenQ] := x;
ff[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
ff[0] /; ($tag1; True) = 0;
ff[1] /; ($tag1; True) = 10;
```

So that

```
ff[1]

(* Sin[1] *)
```

But then you considerably slow down the lookup for such definitions, even when they eventually fire.

Comment: *We can attempt to reorder manually:
`DownValues[ff] = DownValues[ff][[{3, 4, 5, 1, 2}]]`
only to discover that this didn't work:* very insightful, +1

Answer (score 22):

Actually we have direct control over this via a System Option.  Set:

```
SetSystemOptions["DefinitionsReordering" -> "None"];
```

Then:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := Sin[x];
f[x_?EvenQ] := x;
f[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[3/2], f[Newton]}
```

> ```
> {Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[3/2], Sin[Newton]}
> ```

Restore the default behavior with:

```
SetSystemOptions["DefinitionsReordering" -> "Default"];
```

By the way this reordering takes significant time; by disabling it I was able to make an already efficient solution more than twice as fast for [How to select minimal subsets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8154/how-to-select-minimal-subsets/8160#8160)

---

#### Prophylactic

Leonid expressed concern about the generality of the effect of this setting.  Here is an attempt to localize its behavior.

```
SetAttributes[nonOrder, {HoldFirst, SequenceHold}]

nonOrder[{body_}] :=
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions["DefinitionsReordering" -> "None"],
    body,
    SetSystemOptions["DefinitionsReordering" -> "Default"]
  ]

nonOrder[LHS_ = RHS_] := nonOrder[LHS, RHS]
nonOrder[LHS_, RHS_] := nonOrder @ {LHS = Unevaluated @ RHS}
nonOrder[sd : (LHS_ := RHS_)] := nonOrder @ {sd}
```

With this internal definitions made during the evaluation of the right hand side in `Set` are ordered normally.

```
ClearAll[f, foo, bar, baz]

foo[] := (bar[x_] := Sin[x]; bar[x_?OddQ] := x^2; baz)

nonOrder[  f[1] = foo[]  ];
nonOrder[  f[x_ /; x > 1] := 2 + 2  ]

?f
?bar
```

> ```
> Global`f
>
> f[1]=baz
>  
> f[x_/;x>1]:=2+2
>
>
> Global`bar
>
> bar[x_?OddQ]:=x^2
>  
> bar[x_]:=Sin[x]
> ```

Note that `f` is *not* automatically ordered, as intended, while `bar` *is* ordered, as intended.

Comment: Interesting. I forgot about this option, +1. Will still keep my answer, since it describes alternative techniques and gives some extra info.

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about this option. +1

Comment: @Leonid We're still writing complementary answers IMO.  Mine is short but hopefully pithy, and yours is extensive and views the problem from multiple angles.  I'll *never* match your Guru badge count but I think we make a good duo.

Comment: Actually, using this option in practice is pretty scary, since it changes the ordering policy globally. So if some of the code that runs during the time when this stays changed, relies in automatic reordering, things can break in very subtle ways. And this doesn't even have to be one's own code, it could be in some of the functionality one is using (perhaps without even knowing about it).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard *"I'll never match your Guru badge count"* - never say never :). *"but I think we make a good duo"* - most certainly.

Comment: @Leonid That is a point worth acknowledging, but at the same time I see it as an edge case as my own definitions, at least those I would be setting manual ordering for, are not ones where I would be running a bunch of code on the RHS.  Can you think of a case where you would *both* want manual ordering *and* be evaluating code that would as a side-effect be creating other definitions?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure, I can. In my own code, I frequently have internal functions (say, local to `Module`), which have several overloaded definitions. So these are created at run-time, and that internal local function becomes a closure. Now, say you use some such function, e.g. as a part of using my package for your purposes,  without knowing about this implementation detail, and call it from your function already after you changed this option. Then, that function would break, in a way that would look like a complete mystery to you, unless you dig into the implementation.

Comment: @Leonid I can certainly see how it *could* happen, I am just wondering how likely it is.  Surely it would be best *not* to leave this set to `"None"` outside of defining the function itself, and I'll be updating my answer soon to address that.  However my definitions are typically either `Set` with a simple fairly simple `RHS`, or `SetDelayed` where I do not believe your concern would apply?  Anyway, as always you make me think. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This becomes pretty likely scenario if you use some third-party functions in your code (and, due to the lack of fundamental distinction between built-in and library / package functions, those can also be built-in and implemented on the top-level), *and* the implementer likes this style of coding where closures are created at run-time as inner functions, such as e.g. `myPublicFunction[x_]:=Module[{inner}, inner[y_]:=y; inner[y_?OddQ]:=y^2; inner[x]];` . I personally use this style quite a bit, even though typically I give definitions in the correct order. But I know people who don't.

Comment: @Leonid Please review my update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Looks good to me, and pretty elegant. Personally, I would still prefer direct and local manipulations with `DownValues`, but your  'nonOrder' seems to cover the majority of problematic cases, so this is probably reasonably safe to use. In any case, this is infinitely better than using global option resetting.

Comment: Would it not be possible to localize the options by doing something like ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{SystemOptions},...]``?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP (1) I don't know, I cannot recall seeing that done and I if I have tried it I have forgotten the result.  (2) I don't believe that would address Leonid's concern, which as I understand it is effect of that option *within* the Block for definitions that use evaluation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry for asking something may looks silly;) but why do you apply `Unevaluated` to `RHS` in the third definition of `nonOrder`? Isn't `RHS` already evaluated in the second definition of `nonOrder`?

Comment: @Algohi Good question.  I'm glad someone is actually reading my code. :-)  It is an attempt to make sets within `nonOrder` behave more like they do outside of `nonOrder`.  One can write `foo = Unevaluated[2 + 2];` and then `Definition[foo]` to see that we did manage to set "foo = 2 + 2" internally.  The `Unevaluated` you mention is needed to allow `nonOrder[bar = Unevaluated[2 + 2]];` to work the same.  There are surely other edge cases I did not handle but that one came to mind so I included it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I see, nice trick.
By the way, I have realised (earlier) that if I want to be good in MMA I need to go, in detail, through codes wrote by top SE users (which of course you are on top of them) :).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard does this still work you you? For some reason my definitions *are* getting reordered.

Comment: @b3m2a1 In version 10.1 I still get `{Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[3/2], Sin[Newton]}` from the first code block after setting `"DefinitionsReordering" -> "None"`.  Are you seeing something else?

Answer (score 10):

This is more of an extended comment in response to

> @LLlAMnYP is there a way to do this without knowing the existing definitions in advance? or maybe use Prepend?

You can roll a function like so:

```
SetAttributes[makeDef, HoldAllComplete]
makeDef[f_Symbol, expr_, n_Integer] := 
 Module[{dVal}, 
  Block[{f}, Evaluate[expr]; dVal = First[DownValues[f]]]; 
  DownValues[f] = Insert[DownValues[f], dVal, n];]
```

Then

```
f[x_?EvenQ] := x;
f[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[x_?EvenQ]] :> x, HoldPattern[f[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}
> ```

```
makeDef[f, f[x_] := Sin[x], 1]
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> Sin[x], 
>  HoldPattern[f[x_?EvenQ]] :> x,
>  HoldPattern[f[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}
> ```

`makeDef` takes the symbol for which rules are being set as the first argument, the expression creating the rule as the second argument, and the position at which the rule will be inserted as the third argument.

Comment: @Kuba because when `f` is `Block`ed, there's only one `DownValue` made. Of course, I didn't generalize this to the cases where `expr` is a big long compound expression that creates several `DownValue`s

Comment: And of course, this also suppresses routines that check pattern specificity and all that, so you can end up with multiple entries of the form `{f[x_] :> dVal1, f[x_] :> dVal2}` and so on. But it's just a little example that shows how to have more control over the order of rules.

Comment: Right, wasn't paying attention, sorry :)

Comment: Wow great answer! I was writing my own (below) when you published this so I didn't see, but this is even better!

Comment: @LiorBlech Yes, `makeDef[f, expr, 1]` is equivalent to your approach, but saves you the trouble of writing out `HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> stuff` and lets you use the usual syntax.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated**

*Updated twice, once to force autoloading, and a second time to eliminate duplicate *Values*

I will answer the last part of the question, specifically:

> Or conversely to make sure a definition is used first even though it was declared last?

Here is a variant of @LLlAMnYP's approach. Instead of defining a new function to insert a DownValue in front of the others, I will use a wrapper to indicate to [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed) that a DownValue should be inserted in front (I owe this idea to @TaliesinBeynon):

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First@Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    (* Force autoloading of sym *)
    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    (* Autloading can cause a symbol to become protected *)
    Unprotect[sym];

    (* Insert new values in front *)
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_, n_] :> insertValues[n, values, sym],
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]

insertValues[n_, v_, sym_] := If[n =!= {},
    v[sym] = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
        Join[n, v[sym]],
        equivalenceClass
    ]
]

equivalenceClass[lhs_ :> rhs_] := If[FreeQ[Hold[rhs], Condition],
    lhs,
    lhs :> rhs
]
```

A few comments.

1. I use `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` because it returns all the *Values definitions, and so I can pick off the one that changed, and prepend the new definition to the right *Values function.
2. I automatically unprotect (and if needed, reprotect) the symbol so that the function will work with [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected) symbols.
3. *(updated)* I include the lines `sym;` and `MakeBoxes[sym[], TraditionalForm];` so that any package autoloading for `sym` occurs before I prepend the new *Value. Using `sym;` causes autoloading of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) and [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) as necessary, while `MakeBoxes[sym[], TraditionalForm]` causes autoloading of [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues). Previously I just used `sym;` but that didn't cause [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) to be autoloaded. Forcing autoloading before creating the *Values is necessary, otherwise the autoloading can occur after the new *Value is added, possibly reordering the *Values so that the new *Values is not in the first position.
4. *(updated)* I also added another `Unprotect[sym]`, because some autoloading packages cause the symbol to get reprotected.
5. *(updated)* My second update deletes duplicates *Values.

Now, let's see it in action:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_?EvenQ]:= x;
f[x_?OddQ]:= x^2;
Initial[f] /: f[x_] := Sin[x]
```

Let's check the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of `f`:

```
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> Sin[x], HoldPattern[f[x_?EvenQ]] :> x,
> HoldPattern[f[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}

Sure enough, it is first, and the desired OP output is obtained:

```
{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[3/2], f[Newton]}
```

> {Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[3/2], Sin[Newton]}

Comment: +1. This answer is actually based on the same set of ideas as [this old answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2795/81) - namely, blocking the symbol and cloning definitions. Your code is in some ways better, however.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks. I actually searched for that question, but couldn't find it, so I added an answer to this question instead. I do like the way I packaged up the answer, but of course, much of the credit should go to LLlAMnYP and Taliesin Beynon.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to LLlAMnYP's comment (and Jason B's example of it) I've determined the best solution to my situation would be:

```
In[1]:= Clear[f];
In[2]:= f[x_?EvenQ] := x;
In[3]:= f[x_?OddQ] := x^2;
In[4]:= DownValues[f]=Prepend[DownValues@f, HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> Sin[x] ];
In[5]:= DownValues[f]
Out[5]:= {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> Sin[x], HoldPattern[f[x_?EvenQ]] :> x, 
HoldPattern[f[x_?OddQ]] :> x^2}
```

As can be seen, the Sin rule would be tried first even though it is not the most specific (the effect is the same as in Jason B's answer).
The Reason this is any different than Jason B's answer is that in this implementation you don't need any information of the existing DownValues of f, as well as being much shorter for more intricate cases.

Thanks a bunch!

Lior