# How to cache results of WebImageSearch?

Tags: image, web-access, searching

Every call to `WebImageSearch` costs money (wolfram service credits), thus, I would like to page through results without having to redownload them.

Given the following search how would one retrieve items 6-10 (without repurchasing the first 5)?

```
WebImageSearch["desert plains", "Thumbnails", MaxItems -> 5]
```

[image]

**Update**

Response to @kuba's question in the comments:

[image]

**Update 2**

@b3m2a1's solution doesn't run for me:

```
vgBlock[fn_, HoldPattern[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs_], expr_] := Module[
    {$recurse},
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{fn},
    Unprotect[fn];
 (lhs /; ! TrueQ[$recurse] := Block[{$recurse = True}, rhs]);
    DownValues[fn] = SortBy[DownValues[fn], FreeQ[$recurse]];
    expr
   ]
];
vgBlock~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
Options[googleImageSearch2]=Join[Options[WebImageSearch], {"StartingFrom" -> 1}];
googleImageSearch2[params:Except[_?OptionQ].., ops:OptionsPattern[]] :=
 vgBlock[GCSFormatRequestParameters, GCSFormatRequestParameters[e___] := GCSFormatRequestParameters[e] /. ("start" -> "1") -> ("start" -> ToString[OptionValue["StartingFrom"]]),
  WebImageSearch[params,  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{Method -> "Google",  ops}, Options @ WebImageSearch]
  ]
]
```

When I run `googleImageSearch2["sweet dee", "MaxItems" -> 4]`, the progress bar starts working but then fails and the symbols turn red:

[image]

Ah ok, `WebImageSearch` stopped working because I ran out of service credits:

[image]

Probably should have warned me!

Comment: Can you add a code which shows `$CloudCreditsAvailable` changing? I can't reproduce it. And can you confirm that those results are not cached, e.g. when you call MaxItems->10 next time, does it take doubled amount or?

Comment: @Kuba it's not cloud but service credits - both cost money.

Comment: Try with less items so not to draw down credits `$ServiceCreditsAvailable`
`Put[WebImageSearch["desert plains", "Thumbnails", MaxItems -> 5], 
 LocalObject["myimages"]]`
`$ServiceCreditsAvailable` 
Then 
`Get[LocalObject["myimages"]]`
`$ServiceCreditsAvailable` 
credits remain the same as previous call.

Comment: The only idea I have for getting the next 5 would be to use `Except[q]`. But the documentation is of no help there the only metadata I could see of use is `ByteCount`. So `Map[ByteCount[#] &, a]` where `a` is the result from `Get[...]` But I found no good examples.

Comment: The function that implements this (for Google search) is ``WebSearch`Private`GCSPaginationCalls`` and it looks like it's terribly designed. The result count is hard coded. The start point can't be set via parameter. Etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it looks like the only real way to do this is by hacking the <strike>mainframe</strike> package that underlies this. Everything seems to be clumsy and hard coded, so I had to dig a little. The following works for Google, but it is easily adaptable to Bing.

The main function of interest is `GCSFormatRequestParameters` which formats request parameters to Google Custom Search. When you use this it hard codes a `"start"->"1"`. We want to specify our own starting point so we will simply hack this function to do our bidding before it passes the parameters to the API call.

First a function to implement a single Villegas-Gayley redefinition in a general manner:

```
vgBlock[fn_, 
   HoldPattern[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs_], 
   expr_
   ] :=
  Module[{$recurse},
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{fn},
    Unprotect[fn];
    (lhs /; ! TrueQ[$recurse] :=
      Block[{$recurse = True}, rhs]);
    DownValues[fn] = SortBy[DownValues[fn], FreeQ[$recurse]];
    expr
    ]
   ];
vgBlock~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
```

Then we'll use this to override the old results:

```
Options[googleImageSearch2] =
  Join[
   Options[WebImageSearch],
   {
    "StartingFrom" -> 1
    }
   ];
googleImageSearch2[params : Except[_?OptionQ] .., 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 vgBlock[GoogleCustomSearchFunctions`GCSFormatRequestParameters,
  GoogleCustomSearchFunctions`GCSFormatRequestParameters[e___] :=

   GoogleCustomSearchFunctions`GCSFormatRequestParameters[e] /. ("start" -> "1") -> ("start" -> 
       ToString[OptionValue["StartingFrom"]]),
  WebImageSearch[params,  
   Sequence @@ 
    FilterRules[{Method -> "Google",  ops}, Options@WebImageSearch]
   ]
  ]
```

And finally we can test that it works:

```
googleImageSearch2["doggo", "MaxItems" -> 4]
```

[image: doggo 4]

```
googleImageSearch2["doggo", "MaxItems" -> 4, "StartingFrom" -> 3]
```

[image: doggo 4+3]

One useful note when digging make sure wrap any calls to `WebImageSearch` in:

```
Block[
 {
  WebSearch`Private`GCSPaginationCalls,
  WebSearch`Private`BSPaginationCalls
  },
 doop doop
 ]
```

So that you can test the parameters without actually searching / downloading the results

Comment: This is fairly impressive!

Comment: I'd like to award you the points, but I can't get this working on my Mathematica OSX 10.13.4 with v11.3

Comment: @M.R. which `Method` to `WebImageSearch` are you using? It looks like it defaults to Bing. Another possibility is that the definition reordering I attempted to impose isn't working.

Comment: @b3m2a1 see my update for how it fails, your vgBlock is fancy and deserves the points by itself btw

Comment: @M.R. I think the problem was I forgot to include the full context for the function I was overloading: ``GoogleCustomSearchFunctions`GCSFormatRequestParameters``. On the other hand your lack of any results is weird. The current version I have up with that context fix returns what I would expect for v11.3.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I just pasted your code as written, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @M.R. My old version was broken. Try copying and pasting the definition for ``googleImageSearch2`` again. It should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77768/discussion-between-m-r-and-b3m2a1).

Comment: See my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) to [(106068)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) for another implementation of something similar to your `vgBlock`.

Comment: @CarlWoll I remember seeing that one. Good trick. And I think Leonid and Mr. Wizard and others have a few implementations of this trick lying around. I just didn't want to search one up to link against.