# How to force TeXForm not to use "array" environment for a square array?

Tags: latex

The default behavior of  Mathematica,

transforms a jagged array

```
TeXForm[{{1, 2}, {3}}]
```

to

```
\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}
```

but

a square array

```
TeXForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

to

```
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

## Question

Is  it possible to produce

```
\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}
```

for `TeXForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
TeXForm[HoldForm /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]

\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}
```

This basically prevents `TeXForm` from recognizing the expression as a matrix.

Using `HoldForm` to prevent or force certain interpretations is also mentioned in the MaTeX documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility which seems to work is

```
lis={{1,2},{3,4}}
TeXForm[InputForm@lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which renders as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hmmm... The output of `TeXForm` is not easy to predict.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) works by formatting the input using [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), and then converting that format to [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm). Specifically, it creates [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes from the input, and then converts those boxes to [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm). TraditionalForm uses [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) to format matrices, and the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) for [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) boxes uses the array environment. So, if you want to avoid the array environment, you will need to either avoid [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm), or modify the way [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) operates on [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) boxes.

The other answers avoided [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) by inserting a wrapper into the expression such that [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) no longer tries to use [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm). However, this means you need to modify your input. I will present an alternate approach where you don't need to modify your input. It will be convenient to make use of my [`Initial`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function, which I reproduce below:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

The `Initial` wrapper is used to force the new definition to be used before the old definitions. In our case, we want to add the following [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) for [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm):

```
Initial[TraditionalForm] /: 
    MakeBoxes[x_List /; TrueQ@$TeX, TraditionalForm] := MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]
```

Now, [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) formatting of matrices will depend on the value of `$TeX`:

```
$TeX = False;
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TraditionalForm

$TeX = True;
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This means that [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) will be similarly affected:

```
$TeX = False;
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
$TeX = True;
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TeXForm
```

> $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$

Finally, it would be convenient if [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) automatically sets `$TeX` to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True), which we can achieve by again using the `Initial` wrapper:

```
$TeX =.;
Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
        {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```

Now, when we use [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), we get the usual [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) output:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

while when we use [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm), we get the desired non-[`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) output:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} //TeXForm
```

> $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$