# How to define floor/ceiling like TraditionalForm?

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form

We have

```
Floor[x]//TraditionalForm
```

with output

```
⌊x⌋
```

If we define

```
FracPart[x_]:=x-Floor[x]
```

How can we get

```
FracPart[x]//TraditionalForm
```

to output something like

```
{x}
```

Comment: Well certainly you won't get $\{ x \}$ as the curly brackets denote lists in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I actually want to get this in LaTeX form. I am not really using the Traditional Form in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this by giving `FracPart` a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) formatting rule:

```
MakeBoxes[FracPart[x_], TraditionalForm]:=TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[x,TraditionalForm]},
    "FracPart",
    DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{"{",#, "}"}]&),
    Tooltip->"Fractional part"
]
```

Then:

```
FracPart[x^2-1] //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Using a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) ensures that copy/paste produces a `FracPart` object instead of a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List) object, and the [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip) is a useful reminder that the braces are used to represent the `FracPart` function instead of a list.

**Addendum**

The OP asks how this format can be extended to `Inactive[FracPart]`. Since `FracPart` would be too deep for [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) to work, one needs to modify the [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) symbol instead. However, [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) already has many [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) defined, and one needs to define the new [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) so that it takes precedence over the already existing ones. One way to do this is with my [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function, which I reproduce below:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

Then, use the `Initial` wrapper:

```
Unprotect[Inactive];
Initial[Inactive] /: MakeBoxes[Inactive[FracPart][x_], TraditionalForm] := TemplateBox[
    {MakeBoxes[x,TraditionalForm]},
    "FracPart",
    DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{"{",#,"}"}]&),
    Tooltip->"Fractional part"
]
Protect[Inactive];
```

Here is the formatting in action:

```
Inactive[FracPart][2.3] //TraditionalForm
```

> {2.3}

Comment: Is there any way to make this work for `Inactive[FracPar][x^2-1]`?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Stork's comment, your requested notation is ill advised. If you still want to shoot yourself in the foot, try the following.

```
Clear[FracPart];

FracPart[x_?NumericQ] := x - Floor[x];

FracPart /: Format[FracPart[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
 Interpretation[
  RawBoxes[RowBox[{"{", ToBoxes[x, TraditionalForm], "}"}]], 
  FracPart[x]]
```

The condition in the definition is so that only numerical values expand.

```
{FracPart[5/4], FracPart[x], FracPart[x] // TraditionalForm}
(*{1/4, FracPart[x], {x}}*)
```

The downside of using `TraditionalForm` is that the wrap prevents further calculations.

```
TraditionalForm[1] - 1
(* -1 + 1 *)
```