# DateHistogram FrameLabel overlaps FrameTicks

Tags: bugs, labeling, histograms

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.3.0**

---

```
d1 = {DateObject[{2010, 10, 4}], DateObject[{2019, 2, 25}]};

d2 = {DateObject[{2000, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2018, 9, 4}]};

DateHistogram[d1, "Year", FrameLabel -> {"Year"}, PlotLabel -> "M", Frame -> True]
```

The FrameLabel "Year" overlaps the FrameTicks values

[image]

Happens when the date format of the ticks is YYYY. If the range of years is expanded, the format is MM/DD/YY and there is no overlap.

```
DateHistogram[d2, "Year", FrameLabel -> {"Year"}, PlotLabel -> "M", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

This looks like a bug in both 11.3 and 12.0. I have reported it to WRI. Will update when I hear back.

Any suggestions for workarounds, apart from using `Labeled` rather than `FrameLabel` and `PlotLabel`?

**Update 2019-04-22**

WRI has confirmed that this is a bug. CASE:4248494

They suggested this workaround that uses `PlotRangePadding`. Apart from the poor aesthetics, it will also require the padding to be adjusted unless the same date format is used for both cases.

```
DateHistogram[d1, "Year", 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Year"}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.15]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DateHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram) has two kinds of frame ticks: ordinary ticks and categorical ticks.  Ordinary ticks are those that are created by the [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks) option, while categorical ticks are actually included as graphics primitives. This is why the categorical ticks have a clashing frame label. Let's use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) to see the internal call to [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram):

```
TracePrint[
    DateHistogram[d1,"Year",FrameLabel->{"Year"},PlotLabel->"M",Frame->True],
    _Histogram
];
```

> Histogram[System`TimeVisualizationsDump`modelData\$2871[WrappedValues],System`TimeVisualizationsDump`timebinning\$2871,Automatic,System`TimeVisualizationsDump`opts\$2871]
>
> Histogram[{3495139200,3760041600},{{3471292800,3502828800,3534364800,3565987200,3597523200,3629059200,3660595200,3692217600,3723753600,3755289600,3786825600}},Automatic,{Axes->{False,True},ChartLabels->{None,None},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Year},FrameTicks->{{Automatic,Automatic},{None,Automatic}},GridLines->{None,None},PlotLabel->M,PlotRange->{{Automatic,Automatic},{Automatic,Automatic}}}]

Notice that the [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks) option is:

```
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}
```

The option suppresses any frame ticks on the bottom frame so that the categorical "ticks", which are actually graphics primitives can be shown.

So, what can be done to fix this? One possibility is to have [`DateHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram) use [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks) of the form:

```
FrameTicks -> {
    {Automatic, Automatic},
    {{{Median[AbsoluteTime /@ d1], Style["1", FontOpacity->0]}}, Automatic}
}
```

when calling [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram), so that an invisible tick is placed in the middle of the bottom frame, causing the frame label to be lowered to accommodate it. I will do this by adding some conditioned downvalues to [`DateHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram) and [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram).

To do this it will be convenient to use my [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function (which I reproduce below) to insert these new [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) at the beginning:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new=Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym,lhs,rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    Unprotect[sym];
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_,n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

The new [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues):

```
Initial[Histogram] /: Histogram[v_, b_, h_, o:OptionsPattern[]] /; TrueQ @ $FixH := 
Block[{$FixH = False},
    If[MatchQ[OptionValue[FrameTicks], {{Automatic,Automatic},{None, Automatic}}],
        Histogram[
            v, b, h,
            FrameTicks -> {
                {Automatic, Automatic},
                {{{Median[v], Style["1", FontOpacity->0]}}, Automatic}
            },
            o
        ],
        Histogram[v, b, h, o]
    ]
]

Initial[DateHistogram] /: DateHistogram[a__] /; !TrueQ @ $FixDH := Block[
    {$FixH = True, $FixDH = True},

    DateHistogram[a]
]
```

Test:

```
DateHistogram[d1, "Year", FrameLabel->{"Year"}, PlotLabel->"M", Frame->True]
```

[image]

```
DateHistogram[d2, "Year", FrameLabel->{"Year"}, PlotLabel->"M", Frame->True]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer has the same issue as the answer from @m_goldberg. I experimented with various options and positions for `Pane`, but was unable to get the distance between the axis and the label to match in both cases using identical options and positions. Seems like there is no way to position relative to the baseline of the tick values.

Comment: Nice. Should this be something that is done automatically by Mma?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Carl. It is going to take me a while to understand how this works.

Answer (score 3):

If the other two answers are not satisfactory maybe try using adjustment boxes, but that might lead to the same issue. I suspect you might need to make your final code conditional to meet your requirements

```
DateHistogram[d1, "Year", 
 FrameLabel -> {DisplayForm@
    AdjustmentBox["Year", BoxBaselineShift -> 0, 
     BoxMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}}]}, PlotLabel -> "M", 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
DateHistogram[d1, "Year",
 FrameLabel -> {"\nYear"},
 PlotLabel -> "M",
 Frame -> True]
```

as a simple work-around? Produces

[image: histogram]

Comment: I have several `DateHistogram`'s with varying date ranges that I am displaying in a grid. Apologies for not mentioning that in my question. This answer works well for the case when there is overlap, when there is not, the label is too far from the axis and that is very obvious in the grid. I suppose I could conditionally add the newline based on the number of bins.