# Return definition that would be applied to an expression

Tags: subvalues

Say I have an expression that has multiple subvalues how do I return the definition that would be applied to it.

Say I define for example:

```
fun[y_][x_] := {x, y};
fun[3][x_] := 2;
```

Then I would like `findSubValue[fun[3][5]]` to return `HoldPattern[fun[3][x_]] :> 2`.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this:

```
SetAttributes[FindMatchingSubValue, HoldAll];
FindMatchingSubValue[sym_, expr_] := 
  SelectFirst[SubValues[sym], MatchQ[Unevaluated[expr], First@#] &]
```

Testing:

```
FindMatchingSubValue[fun, fun[3][5]]
(*HoldPattern[fun[3][x_]] :> 2*)

FindMatchingSubValue[fun, fun[4][5]]
(*HoldPattern[fun[y_][x_]] :> {x, y}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works because SubValues are automatically sorted (according to specificity, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106093/45020)  in the list returned by SubValues (or DownValues etc...):

```
SetAttributes[outermostHeadHeld,HoldAllComplete];
outermostHeadHeld[expr_]:=ReleaseHold[Hold[expr]//.Hold[h_[___]]:>Hold[h]];

SetAttributes[findSubValue,HoldAll];
findSubValue[expr_]:= Module[{subvals},
    subvals=SubValues[Evaluate[outermostHeadHeld[expr]]];
    SelectFirst[subvals,MatchQ[Hold[expr],Hold[Evaluate[#[[1]]]]]&]
]
```

The same idea should also work for `DownValues`.