# Display Conjugate[x_] as a long overbar permanently

Tags: output-formatting, complex

In TraditionalForm output, I would like to have Conjugate be always displayed as an overbar, not an asterisk superscript. In particular for complicated expressions like `Conjugate[Log[z]]`, I would like to have a long overbar.

There are various solutions proposed in other threads, including the simplest version:

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Format[Conjugate[x_], TraditionalForm] := OverBar@Pane@x;
Protect[Conjugate];
```

This gives the desired result, but *only the first time* I call `// TraditionalForm` on some output.

**How can I ensure that this new format rule is applied throughout the rest of my notebook?**

PS: As requested here a full MWE with Mathematica 13.0.1.0.

```
Quit[];
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Format[Conjugate[x_], TraditionalForm] := OverBar@Pane@x;
Protect[Conjugate];
Conjugate[Log[z]] // TraditionalForm
Conjugate[Log[z]] // TraditionalForm
```

I obtain the output

> $\overline{\log z}$
>
> $(\log z)^*$

Comment: The docs indicate that output of the form `TraditionalForm[expr]` gets special handling, which can be seen by examining the cell expression of the * form: There's no `*` in it, just a `TemplateBox` that I assume the FE typesets. (Menu Cell > Show Expression, to see it.) I don't know off hand how to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I used is a slight modification of @fqrt's answer using a `TemplateBox` below, but introducing an additional `PaneBox`:

```
Unprotect[TemplateBox];
TemplateBox[x_, "Conjugate", SyntaxForm -> SuperscriptBox] := OverscriptBox[PaneBox[x[[1]], ImageMargins -> 1], "_"];
Protect[TemplateBox];
```

Comment: You're welcome to do this, of course, but I think it's a very bad idea to give DownValues to TemplateBox.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks for the feedback, could you elaborate on possible unintended side effects or similar?

Answer (score 7):

You are encountering two issues.

1. [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) is a symbol which autoloads definitions when it is used or displayed.
2. The autoloaded definitions use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition), making it difficult to force your new definition to be favored.

I recommend using my [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) function to solve these issues, which I repeat here for convenience:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First@Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    (* Force autoloading of sym *)
    sym;
    Quiet@MakeBoxes[sym[],TraditionalForm];

    (* Autloading can cause a symbol to become protected *)
    Unprotect[sym];

    (* Insert new values in front *)
    Replace[
        new,
        Rule[values_, n_] :> insertValues[n, values, sym],
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]

insertValues[n_, v_, sym_] := If[n =!= {},
    v[sym] = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
        Join[n, v[sym]],
        equivalenceClass
    ]
]

equivalenceClass[lhs_ :> rhs_] := If[FreeQ[Hold[rhs], Condition],
    lhs,
    lhs :> rhs
]
```

Then, you can make your new definition with:

```
Initial[Conjugate] /: Format[Conjugate[x_], TraditionalForm] := OverBar @ Pane @ x
```

and you should get your desired behavior.

**Update**

If you really want the argument to be parenthesized (it seems unnecessary to me), then you could do:

```
Initial[Conjugate] /: MakeBoxes[Conjugate[x_], TraditionalForm] := TemplateBox[
    {Parenthesize[x, TraditionalForm, Power, Left]},
    "Conjugate",
    DisplayFunction -> Function@OverscriptBox[PaneBox@#,"_"]
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Is there a way to keep automatic parentheses being added for expressions like `Conjugate[Log[z]+Log[x]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can deal with it through stylesheets, which may or may not be convenient for you.  You can set up a stylesheet for your notebooks or execute this:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Conjugate"], 
     TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction -> (OverscriptBox[
           PaneBox[#1], 
           StyleBox["_", FontFamily -> "Times", 
            SingleLetterItalics -> False]] &), 
       Tooltip -> Automatic}]}]]
```

Note the `TemplateBoxOptions` must be set for the style `"Conjugate"` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

So I tracked the difference between `TraditionalForm` and `DisplayForm` to use of `TemplateBox`. Answer of @Michael E2 is really good, however a more minimal override may be written:

```
Unprotect[TemplateBox];
TemplateBox[x_, "Conjugate", SyntaxForm -> SuperscriptBox] := 
 OverscriptBox[x[[1]], "_"]
Protect[TemplateBox];
```

I tested on following input:

```
Conjugate[c] // TraditionalForm
Conjugate[Log[z]] // TraditionalForm
Conjugate[Log[z]] // TraditionalForm
```

No nasty stars attached.

Comment: I like that this solution automatically parenthesizes expresssions like `Conjugate[Log[x] + Log[z]]`. Is there a way to add the `Pane` object back in to get a more nicely looking output?

Answer (score 0):

This thing is usually done with `Format` function definition.
However `Conjugate` as a built-in is protected. The code snippet to do that is

```
Unprotect[Conjugate]
Format[Conjugate[a_],StandardForm]:= OverBar[a]
Protect[Conjugate]
```

where the last line is optional.
Works quite all right.

[image: Result of snippet]

Comment: I can't see the failing example for what you mentioned, could you provide minimal working example when it stops working?

Comment: Running such a cell twice produces the erroneous $x^*$ output for me, as I stated in the question. See edit of the question to have a complete MWE you can copy-paste. Please note that I care about TraditionalForm not StandardForm.