# Matching HoldPattern expressions

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

My original problem is to delete all rules starts with `a[1]` from `SubValues[a]`

For example,

```
{HoldPattern[a[1][2]] :> 1, HoldPattern[a[2][3]] :> 5, 
 HoldPattern[a[1][x_, y_]] :> x + y, 
 HoldPattern[a[2][x_, y_]] :> x - y, HoldPattern[a[2][x_]] :> x}
```

would become

```
{HoldPattern[a[2][3]] :> 5, HoldPattern[a[2][x_, y_]] :> x - y, 
HoldPattern[a[2][x_]] :> x}
```

I tried to use patterns at first, but I found that when matching patterns with `HoldPattern` head, results become unpredictable.

I found 2 general pattern matching results with `HoldPattern` I don't understand (doc on `HoldPattern` and related did not say anything on this):

1.`MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], HoldPattern[_[_]]]` is `True`, but include some names, and `MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], HoldPattern[a[_]]]` is `False`.

2.`MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], HoldPattern[_[_]]]` is `True`, but `MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1][1]], HoldPattern[_[_][_]]]` is `False`.

I solved my problem with

```
FilterRules[SubValues[a], _?(FreeQ[#, name] &)]
```

But I would still like to know about matching `HoldPattern` expressions.

Comment: You can use `Verbatim`: `MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], Verbatim[HoldPattern][a[_]]]` will return `True`.

Comment: @Xavier can you explain more? I only know how `Verbatim` work with blanks, and I have no idea what `HoldPattern` did to the expression  that caused this mismatch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Clarification of `HoldPattern` usage:**

> `HoldPattern[expr]` is equivalent to `expr` for pattern matching, but maintains `expr` in an unevaluated form.

I think this can be ambiguous for beginners. One could think that what we are doing in

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], HoldPattern[_[_]]]
```

is to more or less

```
MatchQ[ a[1], _[_] ]
```

where both arguments are kept unevaluated. That's not the case. *"for pattern matching"* from the usage message means *"when used in pattern"*. And here a pattern is the second argument.

Knowing that we can easily explain your examples:

---

So, **case 1**,

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1]], HoldPattern[_[_]]]
```

is really trying to match `_[_]` to `HoldPattern[a[1]]`, with success because it really is `(HoldPattern)[(a[1])]`.

Furthermore, it will fail to match `a[_]` because this represents an expression  which outer head is `a` while it should be `HoldPattern`.

---

**Case 2** can be explained this way too. When the `HoldPattern` is stripped, `_[_][_]` doesn't match `HoldPattern[a[1][1]]` as it really is `_[_[_][_]]`:

```
MatchQ[HoldPattern[a[1][1]], HoldPattern[_[_[_][_]]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

**Possible issues with `Verbatim`**:

To prevent `HoldPattern` from being stripped you can use `Verbatim`. But it can't be used mindlessly. E.g. let's say you have defined:

```
a[_]:=2
```

This will create

```
HoldPattern[a[_]] :> 2
```

down value. As discussed your approach won't work:

```
MatchQ[ HoldPattern[a[_]] :> 2, HoldPattern[a[_]] :> 2 ] (*False*)
```

but also

```
MatchQ[ HoldPattern[a[_]] :> 2, Verbatim[HoldPattern][a[_]] :> 2 ]
```

fails because there isn't anything preventing `a[_]` from evaluating to `2`.

Here we are safe:

```
MatchQ[
 HoldPattern[a[_]] :> 2,
 Verbatim[HoldPattern][a[_]] :> 2 // HoldPattern
]
```

---

**The answer** finally:

```
DeleteCases[
 values,
 _[a[1][__]] :> _ // HoldPattern
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I misunderstood, you even gave me an answer to the "preventing pattern from evaluated" problem I actually encountered but didn't mention. Thanks!

Comment: @happyfish related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2804/121 :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nice! Sometimes evaluation control is beyond my usual problem solving logic, and I'll end up with a pile of spaghetti code. The answers from you and a few others on this topic are always eye opening.

Answer (score 2):

My go to method for handling *Values is to just use `_` everywhere. So, I would use:

```
values = {HoldPattern[a[1][2]] :> 1, HoldPattern[a[2][3]] :> 5, 
    HoldPattern[a[1][x_, y_]] :> x + y, 
    HoldPattern[a[2][x_, y_]] :> x - y, HoldPattern[a[2][x_]] :> x};

DeleteCases[values, _[_[a[1][__]],_]]
```

> {HoldPattern[a[2][3]] :> 5, HoldPattern[a[2][x_, y_]] :> x - y, 
>    HoldPattern[a[2][x_]] :> x}