# HoldPattern vs Unevaluated

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

For learning purposes I created this code:

```
{g, 3*(10 + g)} /. HoldPattern[Plus[t__]] :> (Plus[t] /. g -> h)
```

I am learning about HoldPattern. As I understand it HoldPattern makes sure that the pattern is not Evaluated. If this is the case however, then what is the difference with Unevaluated and why does Unevaluated not work in case of patterns?

Comment: @Kuba, I guess my question is what the difference is between the two in the case of patterns

Comment: Will delete my previous comment as I am not sure I understood the question but I don't have time to focus now. Let me leave the old related link [112842](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112842/5478) and another closer one: [110499](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110499/5478)

Comment: This is the same as asking about the difference between `Hold` (or anything with a `Hold*` attribute) and `Unevaluated`. Google for this and you'll find several discussions (many point to the Villegas tutorial).  `Unevaluated` gets stripped out in the first "evaluation step". Its argument *will* get evaluated during the second step.

Comment: Try `Unevaluated[1 + 1]`, `Unevaluated[1 + 1] + 1` and `Hold[1 + 1] + 1` and `TracePrint` their evaluations.  The first one is a special case because evaluation stops when `Unevaluated[...]` reach the top level. The second one evaluates to `(1+1)+1` which then evaluates further immediately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) is a persistent head that prevents evaluation of its argument(s) yet is transparent to pattern matching.  [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) is a temporary wrapper that prevents the evaluation of a single argument* by a single head at one point in the evaluation, and then is stripped.  Once it is stripped it cannot have any further effect on the evaluation.

You *can* use `Unevaluated` in your example pattern, but it must wrap the entire rule rather than only the left hand side:

```
{g, 3*(10 + g)} /. Unevaluated[Plus[t__] :> {t}]    (* simplified RHS for clarity *)
```

> ```
> {g, {30, 3 g}}
> ```

`Unevaluated[Plus[t__]] :> {t}` would not work *even if `Unevaluated` acted normally*<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110499/why-unevaluated-doesnt-work-on-unheld-side-of-rule-ruledelayed?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sup> because it would only prevent [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) from evaluating `Plus[t__]` but the entire rule would be (re)evaluated by [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and `Plus[t__]` reduced to `t__`.

---

* Although undocumented and even marked in red as a syntax error `Unevaluated` *will* accept multiple arguments, and when activated it effectively transforms into [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) while simultaneously holding.  This transformation takes place after the Sequence would be flattened in the normal evaluation procedure, so it remains as a single expression even if the head (`f` below) does not have [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceHold.html) or [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html).

```
ClearAll[f]

f[x_] := HoldComplete[x]

f[Unevaluated[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Sequence[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3]]
> ```

Observe that `Sequence[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3]` is bound to the single parameter pattern `x_`, rather than becoming `f[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3]` which would not match the definition given.  In other words the behavior is the same as:

```
f[Unevaluated @ Sequence[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3]]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. No single word that is not needed, and yet a complete description. Your text is as terse yet functional, as your code. My hat is off.

Comment: @Leonid I am sincerely flattered.

Comment: @Leonid I thought of something to add.  Hopefully it is useful and does not detract too much from the pithiness of the answer.

Comment: “… because it would only prevent `RuleDelayed` from evaluating `Plus[t__]` but the entire rule would be (re)evaluated by `ReplaceAll` and `Plus[t__]` reduced to `t__`.” Maybe I missed something, but I think it's not true? `Unevaluated[Plus[t__]] :> {t}` will evaluate to `t__ :> {t}` even when it's outside of `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: @xzczd Right, that's what I meant by "even if Unevaluated acted normally" -- see the superscript link next to that phrase for a related discussion.  Perhaps I can think of a better way to write that.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I did miss something 囧 .