# Does Mathematica have a method for achieving the same goals that Aspect Oriented Programming does?

Tags: programming, functional-style, object-oriented, design-patterns

I imagine that this question has been asked before, yet I'm not able to find an answer using the form of the question I believe might be asked.

Is there a mechanism for duplicating the functionality of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

For example, if one has an existing application that accesses a particular set of sensitive files, my desire would be to Log/Monitor/Intercept/Visualize access to and operations upon those files and their data.

Given my shallow faculty with Mathematica I envision that such might take the form:

```
Intercept[FileSystemScan, FunctionThatDecidesWhenBeforeAfterDuring, FunctionThatDecidesWhatToDo, FunctionThatHandlesErrors] 

Intercept[AllFunctionsWithSignatureFooOptionallyIncludingContext,FunctionthatDecidesWhen,FunctionThatDecidesWhat,FunctionThatHandlesErrors]
```

Or something to that effect.

I looked at `Trace`, yet that doesn't seem to be exactly that for which I am looking.  Yet, perhaps I just do not fully understand it.

Comment: Have a look at [UpValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html)

Comment: @Sascha Thanks much.  I confess I am having some conceptual difficulty with Up and Down Values.

Comment: See [(96)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/142) for discussion of up- and down-values.  Up-values are a useful tool to crosscut advice into "call" join points where at least one of the join point arguments has a distinctive head.  There is a [widely used](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=villegas-gayley) idiom known as the [Villegas-Gayley trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/211232) that can wrap advice around a single function (i.e. with little or no crosscutting).

Comment: Also look at [Leonid's `withUserDefs` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2795/14303).