# Handling "vars appears twice in a nested scoping construct" Warning in Custom Function

Tags: function-construction

I've been developing a custom function that serves to simplify the body of other `Function`'s in Mathematica. Here is my function definition:

```
FSimplifyFunction[f : HoldPattern[Function[vars : _Symbol, body_, atts___]], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Block[{vars}, Function @@ FullSimplify[List @@ f, opts]]
```

This function appears to perform as intended for my needs. However, I am encountering a warning stating: "vars appears twice in a nested scoping construct." I understand that this is due to my usage of vars as both a pattern variable in `Function[vars, ...]` and a local variable in `Block[{vars}, ...]`.

Despite the warning, the code seems to operate as I anticipate. Should this warning be a cause for concern? Is there an alternative way to structure my code to avoid this warning while preserving functionality? I welcome any insights.

**Note**: Changing the name of vars within the `Block` affects its behavior, leading to unintended consequences when the same variable name is used globally. To ensure proper scoping and protect the function from global values, we must stick to the original definition of vars.

Comment: Change the name of one of the `vars`? What is the one in the `Block` doing anyway?

Comment: Hi, @Marco! If I modify the name of vars within the Block, a problem arises when vars is assigned as a global variable, which is a scenario I am trying to prevent.

Comment: Do you need to worry about non-vars parameters being evaluated, as in `a = 4; FSimplifyFunction[Function[x, x + a]]`?

Comment: Somewhat similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236264

Comment: This construct is used here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/making-a-symbols-new-definitions-be-tried-before-all-previously-defined-ones/2795#2795

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelE2! I need to carefully read through the references you've shared. Indeed, I need to prevent the evaluation of variables on which the function depends, as in the case of `Function[x, x + a]`.