# How to "ignore" an element of Map or MapIndexed

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Say I have some function that I'm applying every element in a list to... if that element matches some criteria:

```
If[#==<condition>,{#}, <Do nothing> ] & /@ LongList
```

Is there a way to do something like this? I want the result to just not have that element.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Andrew!  I'm curious, how did you find this site?

Comment: It's not clear to me why DeleteCases and similar functions are not the right tools for the job. Or you might perhaps prefer something like this:  Flatten[If[# > 1, #, {Sequence[]}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 0}]

Comment: I think this should be closed as [a duplicate of this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1234/121) but I don't want to cast a moderator super-vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree. I'm not voting because I've also answered it.

Comment: It is in substance but several of the answers to that question were specific to the implementation, testing for `Image` heads or `Missing`. Noone used `DeleteCases`. I think this question would be a better canonical version.

Comment: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297/8

Comment: @Szabolcs: I was actually part of the Area51 "committers" for this site, I have just been busy with other things.

Comment: Related: [(3700)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This specific behaviour can be achieved using

```
If[condition, something, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]& /@ list
```

The key is [`Sequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html).  `Unevaluated` prevents it from disappearing from inside the `If`.

Alternatively you can use `Cases` (or many other solutions shown in other answers and comments---some of these solutions may be better suited for the problem but `Sequence[]` has its place too).

```
Cases[list, element_ /; condition :> something]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  The Select answer I was aware of, but this is much more what I was looking for, I wasn't aware of the "Sequence[]" function.

Comment: @AndrewSpott Though I think this use of `Sequence` is OK here, this function has some peculiarities that you should be aware off, especially in combination with `Part`. Try, e.g., the following code `s = {1, 2, 3} <ret>
s[[1]] = Sequence[] <ret>
s[[1]] <ret>
s[[2]] <ret>
s[[2]] = 1000 <ret>
s[[2]] <ret>
s <ret>` and examine closely the output of the last two lines (every instruction should be on a separate line but that doesn't work here in comments). It will amaze you.

Comment: Weird, is that a bug?  Also, it seems to add some sort of history to the list, which would be ridiculously hard to debug, is there a way to remove that history?

Answer (score 6):

You can combine `Map` (aka `/@`) and `Select`:

```
In[242]:= Sqrt /@ Select[{1, -2, 3, -4, 5}, # > 0 &]
Out[242]= {1, Sqrt[3], Sqrt[5]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In a similar vein to Szabolcs' first solution, you can use `SlotSequence` to achieve the same effect.

```
If[condition, <do something>, ## &[]] & /@ list
```

Comment: `##&[]` evaluates to `Sequence[]` as well.  The difference is that `##&[]` is not expanded in heads with `HoldAll`, while `Sequence[]` is (it needs `HoldSequence` to prevent that).

Answer (score 4):

In versions 11+, you can use [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html?q=Nothing) for `<do nothing>`:

```
If[Mod[#, 3] == 0, #, Nothing] & /@ Range[20]
```

> {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18}