# How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If construct

Tags: conditional, faq, return-value

I need to use `If` but with only one option that is *if "a" then do "b", else do nothing*. So I wrote `If[a,b]` but the problem is that if it is not `a` it returns `Null` in my output.
How to avoid this?

Here is the specific example I was working on.

I am looking for the number of comparisons performed by the quick sort algorithm. Here is the code from [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort) with my additions

```
QuickSort[x_List] := 
 Module[{pivot, aa = 0, bb = 0}, If[Length@x <= 1, Return[x]];
  pivot = First[x];
  aa = If [Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] > 1, 
    Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] - 1 , Sequence[]];
  bb = If [Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] > 1, 
    Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j > pivot]] - 1 , Sequence[]]; 
  count = count + aa + bb;
  Flatten@{QuickSort[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]], 
    Cases[x, j_ /; j == pivot], 
    QuickSort[Cases[x, j_ /; j > pivot]]} ; Return[count] ]
```

Now if you run `QuickSort[{4, 3, 2, 1, 5}]` you will get `2+2 Null` instead of 4.

Comment: What is the problem with that, returning `Null` is usually no problem, the FrontEnd will usually not even create an output cell for that return value...

Comment: ok i my case i could just add 0, in the "else" case. but i wonder why proposal of "kguler" and "ruebenko" that i also tested didn't work in my case

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends what you consider nothing, but you could try something like this

```
If[a, b, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

for example

```
3 + If[False, 1, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

returns 3. Wrapping an argument of a function in `Unevaluated` is effectively the same as temporarily setting the attribute `Hold` for that argument meaning that the argument isn't evaluated until after it's inserted in the definition of that function.

By the way, in your definition of `QuickSort` you're calling `Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]` six times. It's probably more efficient to assign `Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]` to a dummy variable and use that instead.

Comment: `Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]` 4 times, `Cases[x, j_ /; j == pivot]` and `Cases[x, j_ /; j > pivot]` each once. But, a variable is definitely needed.

Comment: @rcollyer you're right, I was a bit hasty in scanning the code.

Comment: `Unevaluated[] == Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`?

Comment: @chyanog I believe this is true: one may use `Unevaluated[]` in any place were `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` is used.   I did not recommend it because `##&[]` is shorter, but it should be understood that `##&[]` and `Unevaluated[]` behave differently, though both are appropriate for this problem.  I added a section to my answer that hopefully explains this.

Answer (score 63):

`If` does not have the attribute [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html); use the "vanishing function" `##&[]` instead of `Sequence[]`:

```
If[# > 5, #, ## &[]] & /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877880/618728) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6078678/618728) for other uses, and [SlotSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) if you are confused by `##`.

---

To further explain the method above, `Sequence` is flattened when it appears as an argument (level one) in an expression with a head that does not have either the `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete` attributes.

For our purpose in `If` one can use any expression which:

- is held unevaluated by `Hold` (More specifically the `HoldRest` attribute.)
- does not have the head `Sequence`
- evaluates to `Sequence[]`

All of these heads meet this requirement:

- `## &`
- `Unevaluated`
- Symbol (e.g. `seq = Sequence[]`)
- `Apply` (e.g. `Sequence @@ {}`)

Observe:

```
seq = Sequence[8, 9];
h = Hold[1, Sequence[2, 3], ## &[4, 5], Unevaluated[6, 7], seq, Sequence @@ {10, 11}]
```

> ```
> Hold[1, 2, 3, (##1 &)[4, 5], Unevaluated[6, 7], seq, Sequence @@ {10, 11}]
> ```

Note that `Sequence[2, 3]` is flattened while all others remain.  An application of `List` will invoke additional evaluation:

```
List @@ h
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Unevaluated[6, 7], 8, 9, 10, 11}
> ```

One sees that `Unevaluated[6, 7]` remains, which is an important distinction, but this is acknowledged behavior* for inert functions like `List` and it will evaluate in other applications:

```
Plus @@ h == Plus @@ Range[11]
```

> True

*[Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

---

**Note:** You may notice red highlighting in the Front End in the expression `Unevaluated[6, 7]`; the multi-argument (and null-argument) form of `Unevaluated` is not documented but it is used internally by *Mathematica*.  You can adjust the highlighting to match by setting:

```
Unprotect[Unevaluated];
SyntaxInformation[Unevaluated] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {___}};
Protect[Unevaluated];
```

---

#### Version 10.2

Version 10.2 introduces the function [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) which is applicable to a subset of this problem.  Specifically `Nothing` vanishes only if the surrounding head is `List` or if it is a non-delayed Value within an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).  Therefore one can write:

```
If[# > 5, #, Nothing] & /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

However it will remain in the output of:

```
If[OddQ[#], #, Nothing] & /@ foo[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> foo[1, Nothing, 3, Nothing]
> ```

---

### Performance

[Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) expressed concern about the performance of `## &[]`:

> I am not extremely keen on `##&[]`. It is concise (and I think clear enough after one understands it), but `Function` invocation is not the fastest operation in *Mathematica*. In most cases (except where the subtle differences actually matter), I would prefer `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` for explicitness and avoiding an unnecessary function call. Simon Woods's suggestion of `Unevaluated[]` could be the best compromise.

Here is a benchmark in 10.0.2 comparing the various methods.

```
SetAttributes[test, HoldFirst]

test[form_][list_] := If[#, 1, form] & /@ list

seq = Sequence[];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  {
   test[Unevaluated @ Sequence[]],
   test[Sequence @@ {}],
   test[seq],
   test[## &[]],
   test[Unevaluated[]]
  },
  RandomChoice[{True, False}, #] &
]
```

[image]

In this log-log scale the methods are so close that it is hard to distinguish them.  Here is another presentation using the average of five runs:

```
rand = RandomChoice[{True, False}, 1*^6];

Mean @ Table[First @ Timing @ # @ rand, {5}] & /@
 {
  test[Unevaluated @ Sequence[]],
  test[Sequence @@ {}],
  test[seq],
  test[## &[]],
  test[Unevaluated[]]
 }
```

> ```
> {0.430563, 0.564724, 0.377522, 0.508563, 0.514803}
> ```

At least on my system `## &[]` appears to be slightly faster than `Unevaluated[]` contrary to Oleksandr's assertion.  Both are a bit slower than `Unevaluated @ Sequence[]` because of an additional transformation step.  (`##&[]` and `Unevaluated[]` both evaluate to `Sequence[]`.)  The assignment method (`seq = Sequence[]`) is the fastest.  However this `Function` is extremely simple; in any nontrivial use the overhead of `## &[]` is likely insignificant.

If the slight overhead or cryptic nature of `## &[]` bothers you I propose using:

```
vanish[] = Sequence[];
```

Comment: If you look at it with Trace, you will see that you are just hiding it: If[# > 5, #, ## &[]] & /@ Range[10] // Trace. In have a year you will not remember what your code does.

Comment: @ruebenko I really don't understand what you are trying to say.  Using `&` effectively prevents (holds) evaluation in `If`.  In a year I most certainly will remember what this code does, barring traumatic brain injury.  What's your point?

Comment: I have the feeling this is in essence replacing the Null with a Sequence; and subjectively makes it harder to read.

Comment: @ruebenko re: "in essence replacing the Null with a Sequence" -- isn't that the idea?  The OP has `If[. . ., Sequence[]]` but it undesirably evaluates to `If[. . ., Null]`.  Using `##&[]` fixes it.  What am I still missing?

Comment: you are not missing anything - I just find that neither Null nor Sequence should be inserted into the list. I find If[cond, a=result]; a cleaner (a little off the track: it can work with packed arrays). That's all I am trying to say.

Comment: +1. Love the `##[]&` trick.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks! p.s. watch your syntax; it is: `##&[]`

Answer (score 12):

I note that all answers so far try to solve the problem of assigning a potential Null value by manipulating the return value. I feel it would be more appropriate to make the whole assignment conditional. Like this:

```
If[condition, aa = value]
```

There's also a small bug in your program (`count` isn't initialized), and, of course, it doesn't sort at the moment. I assume that you aware of that and that the Return value is used for testing.

The code would then be:

```
QuickSort[x_List] := 
 Module[{pivot, aa = 0, bb = 0, count = 0}, 
  If[Length@x <= 1, Return[x]];
  pivot = First[x];
  If[Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] > 1,
     aa = Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] - 1
  ];
  If[Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]] > 1, 
     bb = Length[Cases[x, j_ /; j > pivot]] - 1
  ];
  count = count + aa + bb;
  Flatten@{QuickSort[Cases[x, j_ /; j < pivot]], 
    Cases[x, j_ /; j == pivot], QuickSort[Cases[x, j_ /; j > pivot]]};
   Return[count]]
```

Remove `;Return[count]` to let it sort again.

I'm not sure about the `j < pivot` test in the second `If`. It depends on your intention with bb, but I guess the test should be `j > pivot`.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use:

```
a = {1, 2, Null};
a = DeleteCases[a, Null];
```

May not be efficient, but it works.

Comment: Indeed it does work.  Also, since `Null` can be implicit you can use `a = DeleteCases[a,]` which is rather nice to those of us who like terse code.

Answer (score 7):

The semantics for if is `If[cond,t,f]` if f (False) is not given `Null` is returned.

I am guessing that you need this in a pattern, then you can use Condition:

```
f[x_] := ppp[x] /; x > 0
f[5]
f[-6]
```

OK, here is a different version of quick sort (I found on my disk - I am not sure how the author is...)

```
ClearAll[quickSort1]
quickSort1[lst0_] := 
 Block[{left, right, pivot, lst, $RecursionLimit = 10^6},
  pivot = First[lst0];
  lst = Rest[lst0];
  left = Select[lst, # <= pivot &];
  If[left =!= {}, left = quickSort1[left]];
  right = Select[lst, # > pivot &];
  If[right =!= {}, right = quickSort1[right]];
  Join[left, {pivot}, right]
  ]
```

If someone feels like adding the counter... my brain feels like gum this morning... please go ahead. The point in the above code is to not use the return value of `If` but to set it to a variable.

Answer (score 7):

In Mathematica, “not returning anything” is not possible. An expression that does not return anything has a value of `Null`, even though you only actually *see* this `Null` in certain circumstances:

> **[Null](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Null.html)**
>       is a symbol used to indicate the absence of an expression or a result. It is not displayed in ordinary output.
>
> When Null appears as a complete output expression, no output is printed.

So, `Null` is always returned, but whether it's displayed depend on what you do with this returned value. For example:

```
In[1]:= If[x > 0, 1]; /. x -> -1
(* nothing is output *)
In[2]:= {If[x > 0, 1]; /. x -> -1, 42}
Out[2]= {Null, 42}
```

Answer (score 5):

Wow, Looks like I'm more than a year late to this party, but I thought this would be nice to post. The `Sequence @@ {}` trick. Here it is using Mr. Wizard's example:

```
If[# > 5, #, Sequence @@ {}] & /@ Range[10]
```

> `{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

Comment: This does work, and was recommended by Leonid [at one time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073396/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-constraint-a-built-in-functions-output-in-mathemati/6078678#comment7055066_6078678) but isn't it better to use `##&[]` now?  Do you prefer `Sequence @@ {}` or are you just posting it for completeness?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I didn't know about it until recently I needed to do a time consuming computation and found it in Michael Trott's Programming guidebook. I came across this post but realized it wasn't posted so decided to post it for completeness. I actually liked your `##&[]` trick better.

Comment: Okay.  Completeness is good, so +1.  (I also included this in my answer which I am attempting to make complete itself.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Do you know why none of those methods work with `Compile`? Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Without trying it I expect that it won't work with `Compile` because the possible return types must match.  A work-around would be to use something like `-1` (for a list of otherwise positive integers) or perhaps ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger`` for the "sequence" return and then `DeleteCases` at the end.  This can create edge cases but I don't know of a better way off-hand.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. That's what I did, I was just hoping there was a way to avoid that extra step. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Stumbled over the same problem with `Compile`. Is there now a better solution available than your workarounds. It's kind of a pity. :(

Answer (score 2):

I am well aware that I am reviving an old question here, however I have been using `Nothing` as the third argument of my `If` functions and it has been doing a great job for me.

```
Table[If[Or[i == 3, i == 5], i, Nothing], {i, Range[10]}]
```

> ```
> {3, 5}
> ```

Comment: `Nothing` only helps with lists: `3 + If[False, 2, Nothing]`