# lists of conditions

Tags: expression-test

I have got coordinates in two list of Latitude and Longitude and would 
like to check if those coordinates are in a certain grid

Example lists are:

```
qLon={-7.48333, -10.4667, -8.66667, -7.48333}
qLat={53.5, 52.5, 53.1167, 51.9833, 51.0167}
```

Grid borders:

```
  SLat=47
  NLat=55
  ELon=-15
  SLon=-5
```

My idea was:

```
If[ELon <= # <= WLon, "","Outside Grid"] & /@ qLon
If[SLat <= # <= NLat, "","Outside Grid"] & /@ qLat
```

I would like to merge them, to do the test in one go, like:

```
If[ELon <= #1 <= WLon && SLat <= #2 <= NLat,...
```

but could not get it working.

Another thing is the output; it should only show something if there is a point outside the grid.

Comment: Something like `And @@ Thread[SLat <= qLat <= NLat]`?

Comment: Normally, queries of this sort are not performed against a single fixed cell of a grid.  (When they are, the process is called "clipping" the points against the rectangle defined by the cell.)  A more typical application is to identify which of many cells in a *raster array* each of a given set of points falls in.  Would this perhaps be what you are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the latitude and longitude lists should be the same length, and that `SLon` should be `WLon`.

```
qLon = {-7.48333, -10.4667, -8.66667, -7.48333, -8, 3, 99};
qLat = {53.5, 52.5, 53.1167, 51.9833, 51.0167, 62.1, 50};

{{SLat, NLat}, {ELon, WLon}} = {{47, 55}, {-15, -5}};

MapThread[
 If[ELon <= #1 <= WLon && SLat <= #2 <= NLat, "In", "Out"] &,
 {qLon, qLat}
]
```

> ```
> {"In", "In", "In", "In", "In", "Out", "Out"}
> ```

For the second part of your question you can use the ["vanishing function"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121) `## &[]`, which works inside `If` where `Sequence[]` fails because `If` does not have the attribute `SequenceHold`.  Perhaps you want:

```
MapThread[
 If[
    ELon <= #1 <= WLon && SLat <= #2 <= NLat,
    ## &[],
    Row[{"Out:", #, #2}, "  "]
 ]&,
 {qLon, qLat}
]
```

> {Out:  3  62.1, Out:  99  50}

Comment: Thanks a lot that works fantastic, exactly what I wanted and also thanks for the explanation i didn't know about the "vanishing function"

Comment: @Khali I'm glad I could help.  I always recommend waiting a bit longer before Accepting an answer, as it may discourage someone from posting a better one.

Comment: yeap that's true I will wait a bit longer next time, thanks again

Comment: Does this deal correctly with grids crossing the 180 deg E/W line?

Comment: @Sjoerd I just transcribed Khali's test.  Feel free to extend this answer or post a better one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm without Mathematica at the moment... Perhaps tonight.

Comment: Wow... this "vanishing function" is interesting!... I can remove a lot of DeleteCases from my code in situations like that where Sequence doesn't work. Tks