# What is the correct way to conditionally add elements to lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no “else” condition in an If contruct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct)

I have several situations where I need to conditionally add an element to a list, at various locations in the list. When the condition is not met, I want to add nothing at all, but the only techniques I can come up with result in the insertion of some element. For example

```
{1, 2, If[False, 3, Null], 4, 5, If[False, 6, {}]}
```

produces

```
{1, 2, Null, 4, 5, {}}
```

which is in many contexts thus contains elements that are invalid, e.g., here for functions that expect integers.

I understand that I could use Insert, but that quickly results in hard to parse code, where the positions of the conditional elements no longer corresponds to their position in the list construction code

```
If[True, Insert[#, 6, 6], #] &@If[True, Insert[#, 3, 3], #] &@{1, 2, 4, 5}
```

and which, in any case, produces errors without additional length checks:

```
If[True, Insert[#, 6, 6], #] &@If[False, Insert[#, 3, 3], #] &@{1, 2, 4, 5}
```

> Insert::ins: "Cannot insert at position {6} in {1,2,4,5}"

Is there a form that will allow me to place conditional insertions of items in lists *at the position where those insertions are to be made* within the original list?

Comment: Try `{1, 2, If[False, 3, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], 4, 5}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @sebhofer suggested, you seem to be looking for `Sequence`,

```
{1, 2, If[False, 3, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], 4, 5}
```

A shorter verision that @Mr.Wizard likes using is

```
{1, 2, If[False, 3, ## &[]], 4, 5}
```

Both return what you want

> {1, 2, 4, 5}

In any case, there are probably more efficient ways of accomplish this that are also easy to parse, so I suggest you give us an example and perhaps we can come up with better solutions

Answer (score 4):

This is the more normal approach:

```
DeleteCases[{1, 2, If[False, 3], 4, 5, If[False, 6]}, Null]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5}

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pick list of `True`/`False` values for each element based on your selection function and then use `Pick`.

```
include = IncludeElement/@myData
```

> {True, True, False, True, True, False}

```
Pick[Range@6, include]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5}