# What are the cool kids talking about when they use ##&[]?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, pure-function, hold

All the [cool kids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78657/37) are apparently using

```
##&[]
```

for

```
Unevaluated @ Sequence[]
```

but I have no idea what *either* means.

Please explain what these things are so I can be a cool kid!

Comment: [vanishing function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=vanishing+function)

Comment: p.s. you are so cool I can't even say your name!

Comment: @Kuba: [It takes practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm1yqsWZO_k).

Comment: This is the answer: [3705](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/5478) but question is not really a duplicate so I don't know.

Comment: @Kuba: For reference, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3704/37) is helpful too.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius that's definitely evil. My favorite, though, is from classic who: [Romana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE9hOaR6cdc&t=49).

Comment: Am I the only one who saw this in the "hot network questions" and wondered at first what the (%*# mathematica to do with *$&%ing [grawlixes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86838/what-the-is-that-called)?

Comment: Read about The Standard Evaluation Sequence and Nonstandard Evaluation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html).  This should be a good start.  `Unevaluated`, `Sequence` and `Evaluate` are a bit special and are not handled in the usual way during the evaluation procedure.

Comment: I am not extemely keen on `##&[]`. It is concise (and I think clear enough after one understands it), but `Function` invocation is not the fastest operation in *Mathematica*. In most cases (except where the subtle differences actually matter), I would prefer `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` for explicitness and avoiding an unnecessary function call. Simon Woods's suggestion of `Unevaluated[]` could be the best compromise.

Comment: Ha! I somehow missed this question until now.  I love seeing this get more attention but I think this needs to be closed as a duplicate; it *is* well explained in my existing answer.  Congratulations on a *Good Question* badge. :-)

Comment: @Oleksandr You can see that I included `Unevaluated[]` in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121).  Performance was briefly discussed with Leonid in the [original dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073396/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-constraint-a-built-in-functions-output-in-mathemati/6078678#comment7055066_6078678) (on Stack Exchange) about this.  To address your concern I shall add benchmarking to my answer.

Comment: @rax By the way there was a link to 3705 in the "cool kids" comment all along.  I guess I should try to make those more visible.

Comment: @Kuba For some time now the close text has read **This question already has an answer here:** which makes it reasonable to close in cases such as this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: So the duplicate text should say "**or** already has an answer".

Comment: @OleksandrR. `## &[]` tests as slightly *faster* than `Unevaluated[]` in both 7.0 and 10.0.  Please see the update to answer 3705.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for doing this test. That will teach me for assuming `Unevaluated[]` would perform exactly the same as `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`! The vanishing function is also not as slow as I had anticipated; its 10-20% penalty over `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` is quite tolerable for most applications.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map[If[#==1,Unevaluated@Sequence[],#]&,{1,2,3}]
```

Note the output. The `1` is gone. That's because `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` puts the empty sequence there, that is, "nothing".

`##&[]` is a shorthand that can be used in *most* places for same - `##` is the sequence of arguments, `&` makes it a function to apply to something, `[]` is that something - an empty argument list, so the result is... a sequence that is empty.

Comment: This is great. I think this is what I was [looking for](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14063/37) (in a question that actually almost answers this one, and is a dupe of the one @Kuba mentions above — failing memory!) years ago: something to put in `If` or `Which` when I wanted "nothing".

Comment: Good explanation. I prefer `Unevaluated[]` to `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` though I can see why the latter might be considered clearer.

Comment: So the bottom line is that all these 3 do the same thing: `Map[If[# == 1, Unevaluated@Sequence[], #] &, {1, 2, 3}];
If[# == 1, Unevaluated@Sequence[], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
If[# == 1, ## &[], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};` so use the last one above. It is not only shorter than all the others, but also makes you look much smarter as well.

Comment: @Nasser: Yeah `If[# == 1, ## &[], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};` — I mean, *obviously*!

Comment: @SimonWoods: Is `Unevaluated[]` the same as `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius you can also write `If[# == 1, Sequence @@ {}, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}` which gives `{2, 3}` also. but from now on, I will use `##&[]` to be more cool.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, it works the same in most places that you'll see `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`, but I hesitate to say that it's equivalent. There may be counterexamples.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it is important to get a fundamental understanding of what 
Pure Functions are that goes beyond the understanding using of a syntax. 
Hereafter an non-exhaustif summary of a few key understandings:

1) Pure Functions have they roots in Lambda calculus that forms the 
basis of functional programming paradigm implemented in Mathematica.

2) In Mathematica a Pure Function is simply an expression with the 
head Function that is applied to arguments.

3) Syntactially # represent a slot for arguments, whereas ## 
represent a sequence of arguments

4) Syntactially & represents an operator for declaring an expression 
as a Pure Function

5) Pure Functions have no names and therefore do not create any 
global defintion in Mathematica (in Lambda calculus also called 
anonymos functions)

6) Pure Function can be used within other expressions.

Example to point 2)

```
 Head[# &]
(* Function *)
```

Applying a Pure Function to an argument

```
 Sqrt @ # &[4]
(*2*)
```

this is equivalent to writing

```
Function[x,Sqrt @ x][4]
(*2*)
```

Example to point 3) difference between supplying the first argument or a sequence of arguments

```
Plus@# &[1, 2, 3]
(*1*) 
Plus@## &[1, 2, 3]
(*6*)
```

PS:easy or not? even penguins would understand this..hi,hi

Unevaluted simply holds evaluation of an expression within an argument. Rasher's example demonstrates this well.

Regarding your comment, the difference between ##&[] and Unevaluated @ Sequence[] in the example from Rasher is that

a) ##&[] is short notation for Function[SlotSequence[1]][], which is evaluated to Sequence[], which then is spliced into the result {2,3}.

whereas

b) the kernel evaluates Unevaluated @ Sequence[] to Sequence[] **after** the function If[] has been evaluated, which is then spliced into the final result {2,3}.

Therefore due to the sequence of the evaluation process  ##&[] is Unevaluated@Sequene[] and not Sequence[].

Using Trace and FullForm are powerful "tools" if you would like to go "playing in the league of cool kids". They reveal how short notation is re-written and give insight into the evaluation process.

I would recommend to compare  output of following in order to get better insight:

```
Trace[If[# == 1, ## &[], #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]  // FullForm

Trace[If[# == 1, Unevaluated @ Sequence[], #] & /@ {1, 2,3}] // FullForm
```

Comment: This penguin doesn't understand the last bit, about `Unevaluated`: `## &[1, 2 + 2, 3]` is `Sequence[1, 4, 3]`, so `2+2` got evaluated, right? If so, how is `## &[]` `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` and not `Sequence[]`?

Comment: @  raxacoricofallapatorius, following your comment I have extended my answer. However the short answer is  that It is because of the sequence of the evaluation process that  ##&[] is Unevaluated@Sequene[] and not Sequence[]

Comment: @ raxacoricofallapatorius, I made small corrections for better understanding.....vote for penguins...