# How to remove all dead ends from a undirected graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

so what I want to do is take an undirected graph, and remove all the "dead ends" (that is, vertices that are attached to only one other vertex), but do it in such a way that it does it until reaches "steady state", i.e., it keeps doing this until there are no more dead ends to remove.

For example, here's a starting graph, h:

[image]

I would like it to remove vertices 4 and 5 (and edges 3<->4 and 4<->5, of course), just leaving the loop really.

So I made a really simple function:

```
RemoveDeadEnds[g_] := (

  gcopy = g;
  Do[
   If[EdgeCount[gcopy, i <-> _] ==  1, gcopy = VertexDelete[gcopy, i]];
   , {i, Length@VertexList@g}];
  Return@gcopy;
  )
```

The problem is that, in the case of the example I had above, it just remove Vertex 5, because at the time in the loop when it checks vertex 4, vertex 4 had 2 edges. By the time it removes vertex 5, when vertex 4 has 1 edge (and should thus be removed), it is already past it, so it returns:

[image]

Obviously I could loop it several times. But that's obviously inelegant, and who knows how long this chain of dead ends is?

I can think of another way, but a little messy: you have a nested function so when you remove a vertex, you check the other vertex it was (formerly) attached to, and test that one. But that's not ideal either.

Is there a better way to do it? Ideally some magical Mathematica function that's already built in?

Edit: I implemented the method I said right above, using recursion:

```
CheckAndRemoveDeadEnd[g_, node0_] := (
gcopy = g;
 If[EdgeCount[gcopy, node0 <-> _] ==  1,
   j = First@AdjacencyList[gcopy, node0];
   gcopy = VertexDelete[gcopy, node0];
   gcopy = CheckAndRemoveDeadEnd[gcopy, j];
   ];
 Return@gcopy;
 )

DeleteAllDeadEnds[g_] := (
  gcopy = g;
  Do[
   gcopy = CheckAndRemoveDeadEnd[gcopy, i];
   , {i, Max@VertexList@g}];
  Return@gcopy;
  )
```

Comment: This is clearly a job for `ReplaceRepeated`... (or `//.` in shorthand).

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** It turns out that the built-in function [KCoreComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KCoreComponents.html) does exactly what you need:

> KCoreComponents[*g* , *k*] gives the *k*-core components of the underlying simple graph of *g*.
>
> A *k*-core component is a maximal weakly connected subgraph in which all vertices have degree at least *k*.

```
kccF[g_, o: OptionsPattern[Graph]] := Subgraph[g, KCoreComponents[g, 2], o]

kccF[g0, ## & @@ options]
```

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

You can also use `VertexDelete` with `ReplaceRepeated` or `FixedPoint`:

```
vdF = VertexDelete[#, v_ /; VertexDegree[#, v] <= 1] &; (* thanks: @Guesswhoitis  *)
(* or vdF = VertexDelete[#, _?(Function[v, VertexDegree[#, v] <= 1])] &; *)
```

Using `vdF` with `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
rrF = # //. g_Graph :> vdF[g] &;
```

and with `FixedPoint`:

```
fpF = FixedPoint[vdF, #] &;
```

You can `rrF@g` or `fpF@g` to *remove dead ends* from graph `g`.

Example:

```
options = {AspectRatio -> 1, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexSize -> Scaled[.1], VertexStyle -> Opacity[0], VertexLabelStyle -> 20, 
   BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick], EdgeLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 300};
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 6}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {6, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};

g0 = Graph[Range[6], edges, ## & @@ options];
Row[{g0, rrF@g0, fpF@g0}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image: gradual removal of dead ends]

Comment: Why not `vdF = VertexDelete[#, v_ /; VertexDegree[#, v] <= 1] &;`?

Comment: Thank you @Guesswhoitis; updated the answer with that alternative.

Comment: I'd be curious to see if anything can be shorter and neater than @Guesswhoitis. `vdF` and your `fpF`. +1 for sure

Comment: @LLlAMnYP,  thank you for the upvote. Re shorter/neater,  how about `Subgraph[#, KCoreComponents[#, 2]] &`?:)

Comment: @kguler can't upvote twice, so no need to thank me twice =P Yes, cool, preserves vertex names (?), I like that.

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[RemoveDeadEnds];

RemoveDeadEnds[g_Graph] := 
 FixedPoint[
  Function[g2, 
   Subgraph[g2,
    Select[VertexList@g2, VertexDegree[g2, #] > 1 &]]], g]

{#, RemoveDeadEnds@#} &@
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6, 6 <-> 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's my "one-liner" for graphs with undirected edges.

```
FixedPoint[
 IncidenceGraph[
   Transpose[
    Transpose[
      Normal[IncidenceMatrix[#]] /. {0 ..., 1, 0 ...} -> 
        Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] /. {0 ..., 1, 0 ...} -> 
      Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]] &, graph]
```

Comment: (+1)  This does not preserve the vertex names. A shorter variant : `AdjacencyGraph@
 FixedPoint[Select[Transpose@#, Tr[#] > 1 &] &, AdjacencyMatrix@g0]`

Comment: Thanks. I almost never deal with graphs in MMA, so questions like these always earn an upvote as they force me to learn something new :-)

Comment: ... or `AdjacencyGraph@ FixedPoint[Transpose[# /. {0 ..., 1, 0 ...} :> (## &[])] &, Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@g0]`.

Comment: @kguler, are you sure? The double transpose will return the matrix to the initial state, but can not `FixedPoint` get stuck between two alternating states in this case (for a directed graph)? You are absolutely right, that the conversion back to graph form should be moved outside of the `FixedPoint`. As for `(##&[])`, there was a lengthy discussion somewhere here on the merits of this vs. `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`.

Comment: LLlAMnYP, good point re directed graphs. I should have added "it works in OP's example". Re ##&[]: [the cool kids...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78910/125)