# Alternatives to Sequence[] as a nonexistent expression element

Tags: sequence

I stumbled upon this code by Leonid Shifrin. He uses `Sequence[]` to create void or non-existent output. I was wondering whether this is really the best way to generate non-existent output in that way? What are alternatives? I was looking for a function named Void[] or something, but it doesn't exist?

```
mylist = Range[Range[10]];
oddSublists[x_List] := 
  Map[If[EvenQ[Count[#, _?OddQ]], # /. # -> Sequence[], #] &, x];
oddSublists[mylist]
```

Comment: see [Nothing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Version 11 you can use `Nothing`

Before use `Sequence[]` or `Missing[]`

```
{1, 2, 3} /. (3) -> Sequence[]
```

> {1, 2}

```
list = {1, 2, 3} /. (3) -> Missing[3]
```

> {1, 2, Missing[3]}

```
DeleteMissing @ list
```

> {1, 2}

Answer (score 3):

`Nothing` for version 11. For older versions, there is also `##&[]` and `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`

```
oddSublists2[x_List] := Map[If[EvenQ[Count[#, _?OddQ]], ## &[], #] &, x];
oddSublists3[x_List] := Map[If[EvenQ[Count[#, _?OddQ]], Unevaluated@Sequence[], #] &, x];

mylist = Range[Range[10]];
oddSublists2[mylist] == oddSublists3[mylist] == oddSublists[mylist]
```

> True

See also:

- [What are the cool kids talking about when they use ##&[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78910/125)
- [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no “else” condition in an
  If contruct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/125)

Comment: Do you feel that this question is *not* duplicate of those referenced?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, looks like it _is_  a duplicate.