# Using If statements internal to Table

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to use `If` statements with `Table`?  To give a kind of ridiculous example that captures to spirit of what I'm trying to do, and I'm aware there are much better ways to do this, let's say we want to make an array of even values from zero to ten:

```
Table[If[Mod[k,2]==0,k],{k,0,10}]
```

The output is:

```
{0, Null, 2, Null, 4, Null, 6, Null, 8, Null, 10}
```

We could then delete the NULL entries and have our list of even values from zero to ten.  However, how is this actually properly so that we don't have any `NULL` statements in the output from `Table`?

Comment: @Kuba Right, that looks like the same question to me.  Should I do anything?

Comment: Not necessarily, it will be a sign for future visitors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this :-

```
Table[If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, k, ## &[]], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

Comment: That certainly did the trick.  Could you explain the syntax a bit?  "## &[]" there's no way I would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: Here is a reference: [vanishing function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct/3705#3705)

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference, I'll be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: @Bob2Alice Perhaps `Table[If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, k, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {k, 0, 10}]` is clearer.

Comment: You can also use the expression Nothing which represents an unevaluated sequence and makes your code more readable. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html

Comment: @Takoda Quite so. However `Nothing` was not yet available in Mathematica when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I know. I just wanted to add my $0.02 to this answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 4):

For variety's sake (and because I like Sow and Reap)...

```
Reap[Do[If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, Sow[k]], {k, 0, 10}]][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many alternatives to `If` in Mathematica. One that you might use is rule replacement:

```
Table[Mod[k, 2] /. {0 -> k, _ -> Sequence[]}, {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
> ```

Another is that you might write your own function that does exactly what you want, because Mathematica's `Hold`-related attributes allow you to write many control structures as if they were ordinary functions:

```
Attributes[when] = HoldRest;

when[True, value_] := value;
when[False, _] = Sequence[];

Table[when[Mod[k, 2] == 0, k], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
> ```