# Von Neumann's method to generate points uniformly distributed on a region of a n-sphere surface

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics, computational-geometry, distributions, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to generate points uniformly distributed on a region of a single n-sphere surface (all angles in hyperspheric coordinates are between 0 and Pi/2).

I decided to use von Neumann's method to generate such a distribution from an uniform distribution. Thus, I need to generate values with probability density of

```
norm[dimension_?NumberQ]=:=1  /  (  dimension*Pi^(dimension/2)/Gamma[1+dimension/2]/2^dimension  )  ;
newDens[arr__]:=Module [ {var=arr}, norm[var]*Product[  (  Sin [ var[[k]]   ] )^(k-1)  , {k,2,  Length[var] }  ]  ];
```

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

So, I generate "angles" uniformely in (n-1)cuboid [0, Pi/2] and values between 0 and norm[n] and then compare them with newDens[angles].

Here is my code:

```
generateNeumann[count_?IntegerQ, dimension_?NumberQ]:=(
  norm=1  /  (  dimension*Pi^(dimension/2)/Gamma[1+dimension/2]/2^dimension  )  ;
  normN=N [norm];
  newDens[arr__]:=norm*Module [ {var=arr}, Product[  (  Sin [ var[[k]]   ] )^(k-1)  , {k,2,  Length[var] }  ]  ];

  pointsDistr={};

  For[i=1, i<=count, i++, {
    angles=RandomReal[{0,Pi/2},(dimension-1)  ],
    value=RandomReal[normN],
    surface=newDens[angles],
    If[value<surface, AppendTo[pointsDistr, angles]]

   }
 ]

);
```

Obviously, `Length[pointsDistr]/count` should be about `(Pi/2)^(1-dimension)*norm^(-1)`.

Let's try it for dimension=3.

```
Timing [  generateNeumann[10^3,3]  ]
Length[  pointsDistr  ]
normN

(*  {0.046875,Null}  *)
(*655*)
(*0.63662*)
```

It seems to be good:

```
 decartePointsDistr=Table[{ Sin[pointsDistr[[i,2]]]*Sin[pointsDistr[[i,1]]],   Sin[pointsDistr[[i,2]]]*Cos[pointsDistr[[i,1]]],  Cos[ pointsDistr[[i, 2]]   ]  },{i,1,Length[pointsDistr]}];
 Show[  SphericalPlot3D[1, theta, phi],ListPointPlot3D[decartePointsDistr]  ]
```

Trying to increase the number of points:

```
Timing [  generateNeumann[10^4,3]  ]
Length[  pointsDistr  ]

(*{0.546875,Null}*)
(*6443*)
```

OK too.

But:

```
Timing [  generateNeumann[10^5,3]  ]
Length[  pointsDistr  ]

(*{20.484375,Null}*)
(*21808*)
```

It's very slow and not correct.

What's wrong with large number of points? In R, such a procedure works very fast even when count=10^6.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First likely problem: `AppendTo` within a `For` loop.  Replace both with `Table` or `Array` and report your findings.

Comment: What Mr.wizard says. Anyway, it looks like the commas in the body of your For loop should be semicolumns.

Comment: @Sjoerd the body is contained with `{ }` so I think that part is OK.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard what should I do with conditions (`If[]`) when using `Table`?

Comment: @Sasha My method is here: [(3705)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121)  If *most* of the elements will be dropped it is more efficient to use `Sow` and `Reap` along with `Do`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it works. I've just used `pointsDistr=If[newDens[#]>RandomReal[normN], #, ##&[]]&/@RandomReal[{0,Pi/2}, {count, dimension-1}]` instead of the loop. What's the trouble with `AppendTo` within the loop?

Comment: In *Mathematica* lists are internally implemented as C arrays (as I understand it) and changing the length of the list results in reallocation of the array.  The longer the array the slower the append operation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but I don't like the style. It kind of builts up a return vector (which of course isn't retuned as For doesn't do that). The canonical way of making a For body is (IMHO) using no brackets and separating statements using semicolons.